# C# Async serialization

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro

Is there a way to to serialize class asynchronously?
I'm asking becouse when my program is trying to do this:

```
public static async void Serialize(List<Zajecia> xml_List)
    {
        using (var stream = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.OpenStreamForWriteAsync("Plan list.xml", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting))
        {
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Zajecia>));
            using (XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(stream, new XmlWriterSettings() { Indent = true }))
            {
                serializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, xml_List);
            }
        }

    }
```

Class:

```
public class Zajecia
    {
        public string c { get; set; }
        public string p { get; set; }

        public Zajecia ()
        {}
        public Zajecia(string C, string P)
        {
            c = C;
            p = P;
        }
    }
```

My async serialization is used in navigation function:

```
 protected override async Task OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
            string t = e.Parameter as string;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(t))
        {
            string[] _p = new string[10];
            _p = t.Split('^');
            _lista.Add(new Zajecia(t,( _p[3]+"("+_p[5]+")")));
            Dodaj_zajecia(_p);
            await Serialize(_lista);            
        }
        else
            base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

    }
```

I get only this error instead of serialization of anything:

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.RuntimeClass is
>   inaccessible due to its protection level. Only public types can be
>   processed.

Everything is public in my program and still it doesn't help. 
Any ideas how to make it work?

Comment: Can you show the definition of `Zajecia`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE 2**

I have checked your project. The problem was, you declared `Zajecia` class within `BasicPage1` class. You must declare it as separate class file or within scope of namespace.

**Right Way**

```
namespace Plan
{
    public class Zajecia
    {
     .....
    }

    public sealed partial class BasicPage1 : Plan.Common.LayoutAwarePage
    {
     .....
    }
}
```

**Wrong Way**

```
namespace Plan
{
    public sealed partial class BasicPage1 : Plan.Common.LayoutAwarePage
    {
        public class Zajecia
        {
         .....
        }
     .....
    }
}
```

---

**UPDATE 1**

Here's code for you.

```
public static async Task Serialize(List<Zajecia> xml_List)
{
    using (var stream = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.OpenStreamForWriteAsync("Plan list.xml", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting))
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Zajecia>));
        using (XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(stream, new XmlWriterSettings() { Indent = true }))
        {
            serializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, xml_List);
        }
    }
}
```

Whenever you want to call the method use `await` as prefix, suppose any button click event calls that method then I will write like this.

Suppose `Helper` is my static class

```
private async void btnSerialize_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    await Helper.Serialize(MyZajeciaList);
}
```

Mark one thing I have used `async void` modifier in click event.

Suppose if I am calling method from any other method like `DoWork(...)`, then I will use `async Task` instead of `async void`

```
private async Task DoWork(List<Zajecia> MyZajeciaList)
{
    await Helper.Serialize(MyZajeciaList);
}
```

---

Your code is working for me just change return type of `Serialize` method from `void` to `Task`. You need to call method as `await Serialize(...);`

Comment: U mean I need to place await   Instead of async   ?

Comment: No, you need to use `async Task` instead of `async void`. Always use `async Task<T>` in user defined method, where `T` is return type of that method. Here method returns nothing so use only `Task`. Only event handlers can have `async void`.

Comment: Oh I know what u mean but there no use in returning anything of serialization.... serialization should just serialize it shouldn't return anything ... where I even dont know where can I place return.
If you would paste an example or something i would be gradeful.

Comment: you don't have to explicitly return anything from your method, even though the return type is Task.  The async/await keywords are managing that for you.  THe [thread here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12144077/async-await-when-to-return-a-task-vs-void) gives a bit more insight.

Comment: I'm completly new in async programing so some things are hard for me to understand

Comment: Most of us are new to it :) no apologies necessary, but it is a core concept particularly in mobile and Windows 8 development, so worth the investment to understand the model.  This article is a good jumping-off spot: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh191443.aspx

Comment: Well, I still get same error nothing has changed ... I edited also to show where I call my serialization

Comment: Can you upload your project on cloud drive (SkyDrive, Dropbox, Box, etc) So I can analyze what are you doing wrong.

Comment: I can send it via mail... i'm not using cloud drives

Comment: I already did. But still no response ... didn't have a time but if need I can upload or RS or smth that u will be sure there r no viruses.

Comment: I haven't got any mail from you.