# Return async result to an event

Tags: c#, events, asynchronous, return

Suppose I had and API event, where I had to return a result.
The computation I have to do uses an async method, which creates a control (must be run on the UI thread).

```
private async void API_QueryControl(object sender, APIEventArgs e)
{
e.Result = await CreateControl();
}

private async Task<Control> CreateControl()
{
await Task.Delay(1000);
return new Panel();
}
```

Now, this is obviously not going to work, since API_QueryControl yields before I set the result. I have no control over the API, which means the event cannot be changed. How would I get the event to wait for the result?

Comment: You don't.  You either block the UI thread, change or don't use that method, find a quicker way to compute the value, etc.

Comment: How would I make it work by blocking the UI thread? CreateControl().Result, CreateControl().Wait() etc. causes a deadlock.

Comment: One way to block the UI thread in this case is to not use async... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can block the current (UI) thread, but avoid a deadlock, by using [ConfigureAwait(false)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.configureawait.aspx). Like this:

```
e.Result = await CreateControl().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

ConfigureAwait(false) makes the continuation part of CreateControl - the part after `await Task.Delay` - run on the threadpool instead of the original UI thread.

I assume you have some reason for using async like this, instead of just writing a synchronous version of CreateControl. That would not only be simpler code, it would also use the original (UI) thread to do the work, instead of using a second thread while the UI thread waits for it.

Also note that you should always prevent exceptions from being thrown from `async void` methods - see the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12144077/async-await-when-to-return-a-task-vs-void).