# await Task doesn't work with IEnumerable

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task

I am trying to execute an existing synchronous method asynchronously, however if the method is `IEnumerable`, then it appears to skip over the method.

Here's a simplified version of what I'm trying to achieve.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private IEnumerable<int> _Result;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        DoSomethingAmazing();
    }

    private async void DoSomethingAmazing()
    {
        _Result = await DoSomethingAsync();
    }

    private IEnumerable<int> DoSomething()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Doing something.");

        //Do something crazy and yield return something useful.
        yield return 10;
    }

    private async Task<IEnumerable<int>> DoSomethingAsync()
    {
        //Perform the DoSomething method asynchronously.
        return await Task.Run(() => DoSomething());
    }
}
```

Essentially, when then `MainWindow` gets created, it will fire off an asynchronous method to populate the `_Result` field.

Now `DoSomething` never actually executes. The debug message never appears.

If I change `IEnumerable` to `List`, then all is well. The method gets executed and the result gets populated.

The main reason I want to use `IEnumerable` is because I'd like to make use of `yield return`, it's not exactly a requirement, but it's mainly just a preference. I came across this issue and I've been scratching my head ever since.

Comment: You never enumerate the `IEnumerable<int>` that is returned.

Comment: You should avoid having async void methods, and make it an async Task return type (for DoSomethingAmazing).  See this answer to a different question for more information on async void
http://stackoverflow.com/a/12144426/3745837

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Now DoSomething never actually executes. The debug message never
>   appears.

That's because when you use `yield return`, the compiler will generate a class which implements `IEnumerable<T>` for you, and return the iterator. It looks like this:

```
Program.<DoSomething>d__3 expr_07 = new Program.<DoSomething>d__3(-2);
expr_07.<>4__this = this;
return expr_07;
```

Where `<DoSomething>d__3` is the compiler generated class, implementing `IEnumerable<int>`.

Now, because the iterator uses deferred execution, it doesn't begin execution unless you explicitly iterate it, which you aren't doing.

> If I change IEnumerable to List, then all is well. The method gets
>   executed and the result gets populated.

That's because when you use a `List`, you're materializing the iterator, effectively making it execute. That's why you're seeing the debug message appear.

Answer (score 3):

The result of running the `DoSomething` method is a class that implements `IEnumerable<int>` and will run your code when you enumerate it.  Your problem has nothing to do with using async.  If you run the following code

```
var result = DoSomething();
Debug.WriteLine("After running DoSomething");
var resultAsList = result.ToList();
Debug.WriteLine("After enumerating result");
```

you will get this output.

> After running DoSomething
>
> Doing something.
>
> After enumerating result

Answer (score 0):

Change your DoSomethingAmazing method and it will work.

```
    private async void DoSomethingAmazing()
    {
        _Result = await DoSomethingAsync();
        foreach (var item in _Result)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(item);
        }
    }
```