# How to await for override async function?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await, task-parallel-library

We have a generic `Job` class which have an abstract `HeavyTask` method like this:

```
abstract class Job {
    private Task m_task; 
    protected abstract void HeavyTask(); 

    public void StartJob(){
        m_task = Task.Run(() => HeavyTask());
    }
    public async Task WaitJob(){
        await m_task; 
    }
}
```

And the derived class override the `HeavyTask` function and also make it async:

```
class JobFoo : Job {
    protected override async void HeavyTask()
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        Debug.WriteLine("JobFoo is done");
    }
}
```

Then when we are using this method, it seems that the `HeavyTask()` is not awaited:

```
Job job = new JobFoo();
job.StartJob();
await job.WaitJob();
Debug.WriteLine("All Done");
```

Output:

> All Done
>   JobFoo is Done

If we don't have `async` for the override `HeavyTask`, then it is working as expected. But I cannot guarantee those whose override the `Job` won't make the `HeavyTask` `async`. I want to understand why it is not awaited successfully and is there a way to make sure it will awaited? If you can, could you also explain whether it is a good practice to override a non-async function as async as shown above?

Comment: old async void issue. do not use `protected abstract void HeavyTask(); `, use `protected abstract Task HeavyTask(); `

Comment: Why do you have separate start and wait methods? It looks like you should just have a single `StartJob` method which returns a `Task` and have each subclass decide how the task is created.

Comment: @EhsanSajjad That not the method OP's asking about.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [async/await - when to return a Task vs void?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12144077/async-await-when-to-return-a-task-vs-void)

Comment: Hello @Lee, thanks for pointing this out. Yes, you are totally right. There is no need to have separate `WaitJob` function here.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's not awaited because there's no awaitable (i.e. `Task`) to await. That method has a `void` return type. And you should avoid using `async void` outside of event handlers.

If you want to enable a derived class to use async have the method return a `Task` to begin with:

```
 protected abstract Task HeavyTaskAsync();
```

And if you then need to have a synchronous override return a `Task` synchronously:

```
override Task HeavyTaskAsync()
{
    // do stuff;
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

I don't think this line is awaitable:

```
m_task = Task.Run(() => HeavyTask());
```

What is it spouse to wait for? No value is returned.

how about

```
Task.Run(() => HeavyTask()).Wait();
```

Comment: Do you know what happens when you call `Task.Run(x).Wait()` ?
It offloads the work to another thread but the thread is synchronously waited for. So instead of a single thread doing the `HeavyTask` you require one thread doing `HeavyTask` and one thread waiting for it.

Comment: @Linky, what you said doesn't even make sense. I think wait() only instructs the thread to wait until it finishes the work if it does I/O operation, thus it is the same tread making it synchronize.

Comment: Not really. `Task.Run(() => HeavyTask()).Wait()` is pretty much the same as `Task task = Task.Run(() => HeavyTask()); task.Wait();`

What does `Task task = Task.Run(() => HeavyTask())` do? It offloads HeavyTask() onto another Thread.
What does `task.Wait()` do? It waits synchronously for a Task.
So you're offloading HeavyTask to another Thread but are waiting for the other thread from the original one. 
What benefit comes from this?