# await is stopping the execution of the program

Tags: c#, .net, async-await

I have a simple method which uses `await`.But the problem is that as soon as i reaches to the line the execution of the program is getting stopped , i dont know why.Here is my code..

```
public async void GetUserdetails() {

var upn = "Custom Name";
var userLookupTask = activeDirectoryClient.Users.Where(
            user => user.UserPrincipalName.Equals(
                upn, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)).ExecuteSingleAsync();

User userJohnDoe = (User)await userLookupTask;
Console.WriteLine(userJohnDoe.UserPrincipalName);
Console.WriteLine(userJohnDoe.DisplayName);
Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Any ways to get the execution running and see the values on Console.Please help.Thanks..

Comment: Check out the implementation of the ExecuteSingleAsync, is it synchronous call internally, is it blocking, which might be causing the current issue

Comment: Possible duplicate of [async/await - when to return a Task vs void?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12144077/async-await-when-to-return-a-task-vs-void)

Comment: @GeorgePolevoy How is that a duplicate?

Comment: How is the `GetUserdetails` called? Is this console application? are you calling it in Main() ?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Yes , I am calling it in Main By Object of the Class

Comment: @Lara Stephen's answer below should help in that case

Comment: My guess is that that the operation is not awaited, that's why the mentioned Main it's exiting prematurely.

Comment: Your question needs to correctly suggest that Console is exiting, I guessed its stuck and not proceeding forward, but in reality you have the main thread exiting. Use the answer below to wait till you get the execution finish asynchronously

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I suspect your Console app is simply exiting.

To prevent your Console app from exiting, you should return a `Task` from `GetUserdetails` and call `Wait` on that task:

```
static void Main()
{
  GetUserDetailsAsync().Wait();
}

static async Task GetUserDetailsAsync()
{
  ...
}
```

Note that `Wait` is not normally used in asynchronous programming; it is usually only used once in the `Main` method of Console apps.

Alternatively, you can move the `ReadLine` into your `Main` method.