# Refactoring Async/Await out for parallel processing

Tags: c#, asynchronous, parallel-processing, async-await, task

Still going through a learning phase with C# and ran into a question I needed help with. Considering the following code:

```
private async Task<String> PrintTask()
{
    await Task.Delay(3000);
    return "Hello";
}

private async void SayHelloTwice()
{
    string firstHello = await PrintTask();
    string secondHello = await PrintTask();

    Console.WriteLine(firstHello);
    Console.WriteLine(secondHello);
}
```

Right now SayHelloTwice() will take 6 seconds to complete. However, I want the retrieval tasks to be ran in parallel so that it only takes 3 seconds to complete. How would I refactor my code to achieve that? Thanks!

Comment: Just a comment on the terminology: "parallel" implies multiple threads. What you want is asynchronous *concurrency*, not *parallelism*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct way to do this (without risk of deadlocks) is to use `Task.WhenAll`

```
private async void SayHelloTwice()
{
    string[] results = await Task.WhenAll(
        PrintTask(),
        PrintTask());

    Console.WriteLine(results[0]);
    Console.WriteLine(results[1]);
}
```

Quite often library writers will endeavor to make the "callback" code in a Task run on the original thread that called it. This is often because objects can only be accessed from a single thread.

When using the blocking calls such as `Task.Result` and `Task.WaitAll` the thread is suspended (cannot do additional work) until the `Task` completes.

However as previously mentioned, often times the `Task` will be waiting for the calling thread to free up, so it can be used to complete the task.

So, in the first case, the outter "Task" holds the Thread, and is waiting for completion.

The second case, the inner "Task" is waiting for the Thread to complete.

Ergo neither will ever run to completion.

Comment: If you're going to bring in the threat of 'deadlocks' might as well explain when and where this is an issue.

Comment: This answer is correct I just feel like the whole deadlock explanation is redundant as it has nothing to do with the actual question

Comment: Retracting downvote due to improvements, but agree with Itsik.  I think the focus on deadlocks is unwarranted and risks turning useful advice into an unhelpful and vague warning - especially since this appears to be a console app (where as far as I'm aware, blocking isn't usually an issue).

Answer (score 3):

In general what you want is to start both tasks and wait afterwards.
A straightforward way is:

```
private async void SayHelloTwice()
{
    // Start the tasks, don't wait
    Task<string> firstHello = PrintTask();
    Task<string> secondHello = PrintTask();

    // Wait for results
    string firstResult = await firstHello;
    string secondResult = await secondHello;

    // Print results
    Console.WriteLine(firstResult);
    Console.WriteLine(secondResult);
}
```

What happens here is the call to `PrintTask()` will start execution of the method and once the execution reaches the first `await` that does an actual async operation, the running task will be returned and assigned to firstHello.
The same goes for secondHello.
Then you wait for both to complete and print the result.

This implementation is just an example to simplify how things work. In real-world code you should probably use the `Task.WhenAll` to wait for all running tasks

Comment: How is this different from what OP has?

Comment: Both tasks start at the same time, as opposed to waiting for the first task to finish before running the second

Comment: Ah i see that in the comments now. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

- You can use [Task.WhenAll](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall(v=vs.110).aspx) to await multiple tasks.
- You should also prefer returning a `Task` rather that `void` ([async/await - when to return a Task vs void?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12144077/async-await-when-to-return-a-task-vs-void)):

  ```
  private static async Task SayHelloTwice()
  {
      var hellos = await Task.WhenAll(PrintTask(), PrintTask());
      Console.WriteLine(hellos[0]);
      Console.WriteLine(hellos[1]);
  }
  ```