# Button does not have the correct signature xamarin

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, xamarin

I'm working on a Xamarin.Forms project and I've had this error I cant solve for hours now. I'm hoping that someone has experienced a similar problem previously and can share their experience.

I get `A Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlParseException was thrown`

and this message `Position 23:5. Method EditInfoClicked does not have the correct signature`

My code looks like this.

XAML Syntax:

```
    <StackLayout x:Name="_MapStack">
    <Button BackgroundColor="#40A6FF" 
            WidthRequest="100"
            BorderRadius="3" 
            Text="Edit" 
            FontSize="16" 
            TextColor="White"
            Clicked="EditInfoClicked" />
```

And C# Syntax

```
    async Task EditInfoClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ProfileDetailViewModel viewModel = new 
        ProfileDetailViewModel (Navigation, user);
        var profileDetailPage = new shared.MyProfilePage()

        {
            BindingContext = viewModel
        };

        await Navigation.PushAsync(profileDetailPage);
    }
```

Comment: Return type is Task needs to be void. Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12144077/async-await-when-to-return-a-task-vs-void

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cant have Task for events change to -> events will have to use async void

```
async void EditInfoClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ProfileDetailViewModel viewModel = new 
        ProfileDetailViewModel (Navigation, user);
        var profileDetailPage = new shared.MyProfilePage()

        {
            BindingContext = viewModel
        };

        await Navigation.PushAsync(profileDetailPage);
    }
```