# Xamarin: Method does not have correct signature

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin

I am trying to create simple multi-screen App.

I added `Content Page` and `button` to it.

`MapPage.xaml.cs`:

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class MapPage : ContentPage
{
    public MapPage ()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();
    }

    void ShowMap(object s, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
}
```

`MapPage.xaml`:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:App14"
             x:Class="App14.MapPage">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin Forms!" />
            <Button Text="show map" 
                    Clicked="ShowMap"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

I am getting error: `ShowMap Method does not have correct signature`

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Check if this helps to resolve your issue: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38067982/button-does-not-have-the-correct-signature-xamarin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38067982/button-does-not-have-the-correct-signature-xamarin)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the event handler from `private` (the default if not specified) to `protected`

```
protected void ShowMap(object s, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
```