# async method cannot return void - How can I handle this?

Tags: asynchronous, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a phone application. When a screen displays I start a timer like this:

```
 base.OnAppearing();
 {
     timerRunning = true;
     Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => showGridTime(5));
 }
 async void showGridTime(int time)
 { 
     while (timerRunning)
     {
         var tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
         await Task.Delay(time, tokenSource.Token);
         detailGrid.IsVisible = true;
     }
 }
```

The code seems to work but there is a warning message in the IDE saying that an async method cannot return null.

Given this code can someone help and give me advice on what I should return and if I am going about this in the correct way?

Comment: Just *don't* return void. Return `Task`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [async/await - when to return a Task vs void?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12144077/async-await-when-to-return-a-task-vs-void)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just return a task:

```
async Task ShowGridTimeAsync(int time)
 { 
     while (timerRunning)
     {
         var tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
         await Task.Delay(time, tokenSource.Token);
         detailGrid.IsVisible = true;
     }
 }
```

This is necessary to have the caller of this method know when it is completed and act accordingly.

It is not recommended to create `async void` methods unless you're creating an event or forced to do that in order to meet an interface signature.