# NUnit testing of Async Task fails in C#

Tags: c#, nunit, task-parallel-library, task, moq

I have the following class and the interface

```
public interface IService
{
    Task<double> GetAccDetails(int personId);
}

public class Person
{
    private int _personId;
    private IService _service;

    public Person(int personId, IService service)
    {
        _personId= personId;
        _service = service;
    }

    public double Amount {get; set;}

    public async void UpdateBanckingAcc()
    {
        Amount = await _service.GetAccDetails(_personId);
    }
}
```

I am trying to write nunit test for it:

```
[Test]
public async void Test1([Values(200)]int personId)
{
    const double expectedResult = 20;    
    var serviceMock = new Mock<IAccountService>();

    //Here I tried both options:
    //serviceMock.Setup(s =>  s.GetAccDetails(It.Is<int>(id => id == personId)))
    //    .ReturnsAsync(() => expectedResult);
    //And:
    serviceMock.Setup(s=>  s.GetAccDetails(It.Is<int>(id => id == personId)))
    .Returns(() => Task.FromResult<double>(personId));

    var person = new Person(personId, serviceMock.Object);

    person.UpdateBanckingAcc();

    double res = person.Amount;
    Assert.AreEqual(expectedResult, res);
}
```

And the test fails. For some strange reason I can not debug it.
So the issue I see here is the call :

```
person.UpdateBanckingAcc();
```

it should be

```
await person.UpdateBanckingAcc();
```

but it does not like if I use `await` keyword.

Please advise.

Also one more question: is there something specific in terms of nunit testing for async methods I should test, like task status testing, etc?

Comment: What version of NUnit are you using? Recent versions should indicate that an async void test is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that your method `UpdateBankingAcc` has return type `void` which should be returning a `Task<T>` or `Task`, so you need to change the signatures of it to reutrn a `Task` like:

```
public async Task UpdateBanckingAcc()
{
    Amount = await _service.GetAccDetails(_personId);
}
```

and now you would need to change your test code to be:

```
await person.UpdateBanckingAcc();

double res = person.Amount;
Assert.AreEqual(expectedResult, res);
```

you should never return void from an async method, unless it is UI controls events, you can read about the best practices of using async and await at following :

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx

http://www.tonicodes.net/blog/why-you-should-almost-never-write-void-asynchronous-methods/

[async/await - when to return a Task vs void?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12144077/async-await-when-to-return-a-task-vs-void)

Comment: Please see my recent comment

Comment: The way how you suggested to make the changes - failes.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple rule: `async void` is used for **fire-and-forget** behavior and only for this. If you need `async` method, change it's return type to the `Task`, as @EhsanSajjad said. This corresponds to the unit tests too:

```
public async Task UpdateBanckingAcc()

public async Task Test1([Values(200)]int personId)
```