# async Task vs async void

Tags: c#, async-await, task, void

This might be a very stupid question, but I have the following lines of coding that convert RAW images to BitmapImages:

```
public async void CreateImageThumbnails(string imagePath, int imgId)
{
    await Task.Run(() => controlCollection.Where(x => x.ImageId == imgId)
                   .FirstOrDefault()
                   .ImageSource = ThumbnailCreator.CreateThumbnail(imagePath));
}
```

which calls this method `CreateThumbnail()`

```
public static BitmapImage CreateThumbnail(string imagePath)
{
    var bitmap = new BitmapImage();

    using (var stream = new FileStream(imagePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
        bitmap.BeginInit();
        bitmap.DecodePixelWidth = 283;
        bitmap.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
        bitmap.StreamSource = stream;
        bitmap.EndInit();
    }

    bitmap.Freeze();

    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
    GC.Collect();

    return bitmap;
}
```

When using `async Void` instead of `async Task` in my `CreateImageThumbnails` method, my application processes the images (29 of them) about 11 seconds faster than `async Task`. Why would this be?

***async void***
[image: async void]

***async task***
[image: async task]

The memory usage is much more using `void`, but the operation is completed *much* quicker. I have little knowledge of threading, this is why I am asking this question. Can someone please explain why this is happening?

Also I have done some research on when and when not to use `async void`, but I could not find an answer to my question. (I might just not have searched very well).

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12144077

Comment: `async void` is fire and forget, so nothing keeps track of the async operation (or even makes sure it runs completely), while `async Task` actually keeps a track that can be awaited on.

Comment: Do you await the task when you are using Task?

Comment: @Magnus Yes, when I call `CreateImageThumbnails` using `Task`, I await it.

Comment: If you dont await it, it would be same as using void.

Comment: @Magnus Exactly, but it then gives me the normal "Because this call is not awaited..." warning. I could use it just like that, but I want to know why using *void* is quicker than *Task* :)

Comment: It is not a requirement, you can avoid awaiting. In much cases it should be awaited that's why the compiler warn you.

Comment: Not related to the question but bear in mind that `FirstOrDefault()` could throw a `NullReferenceException` if it doesn't find a match in `controlCollection`. If you are sure it won't happen, you can still simplify it calling `controlCollection.First(x => x.ImageId == imgId).ImageSource = ...`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When you call an `async void` method, or call an `async Task` method without awaiting it (if the called method contains an `await`, so it doesn't block), your code will continue right away, without waiting for the method to actually complete. This means that several invocations of the method can be executing *in parallel*, but you won't know when they actually complete, which you usually need to know.

You can take advantage of executing in parallel like this, while also being able to wait for all the invocations to complete by *storing the `Task`s in a collection* and then using `await Task.WhenAll(tasks);`.

Also keep in mind that if you want to execute code in parallel, you have to make sure it's safe to do it. This is commonly called "thread-safety".