# Implement Onpropertychanged with ObservableCollection (C#, WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, observablecollection, propertychanged

I have ComboBox with "ProjectList":

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ProjectList}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" />
```

Elements are adding inside below method and working ok:

**MainViewModel.cs**

```
[AddINotifyPropertyChangedInterface]
public class MainViewModel{

 public ObservableCollection<string> ProjectList { get; internal set; } 
  = new ObservableCollection<string>(); 

  public async Task GetProjects(){
  ...
   foreach (AItem item in....)
   {
     ProjectList.Add(item.name)
   }
 }    
}
```

Note - I have installed "PropertyChanged.Fody".

Now I have added second ComboBox "TaskList" to xaml:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=TaskList}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" />
```

List here should be created based on selected item into "ProjectList". Method is mostly the same, only has a parameter:

```
public ObservableCollection<string> TaskList { get; internal set; } 
 = new ObservableCollection<string>();

public async Task GetTask(string projectId = ""){
      ...
       foreach (AItem item in....)
       {
         TaskList.Add(item.name2)
       }
 }
```

Now I want to addopt this to my MVVM.

**Problem is**: when and how to run GetTask()? Instead of "internal set" for *ObservableCollection TaskList*  should be implemented "onpropertychanged"?

Comment: Could you clarify your question? I'm not sure what you mean by _"Instead of "internal set" should be implemented "onpropertychanged"?"_

Comment: I think you should look into a Master-Detail-View and consider changing your Project string to an object, that owns the TaskList which you can then bind to, instead of having everything in one ViewModel.

Comment: oh, you mean if you should implement a setter for your ObservableCollection (and thus INotifyPropertyChanged)? Then no, IMO don't do that. Call `.Clear()` and add items again.

Comment: @4est: What does PropertyChanged.Fody has to do with this? The ObservableCollection raises events to the UI when items are added and removed. This has nothing to with INotifyPropertyChanged. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @mm8 -> when you select Project the next cb should load (run) taskList

Comment: See my answer then. You need to call the method when the selection changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when you select Project the next cb should load (run) taskList

Then you should either bind the `SelectedItem` property of the `ComboBox` to a string source property and call the `GetTask` method in the setter of this one, e.g.:

```
    private string _selectedProject;
    public string SelectedProject
    {
        get { return _selectedProject; }
        set
        {
            _selectedProject = value;
            GetTask(_selectedProject);
        }
    }
```

...or invoke a command when the selection changes: Either from the setter:

```
set
{
    _selectedProject = value;
    YourCommand.Execute(null);
}
```

...or from the XAML markup using an [interaction trigger](https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2013/06/30/handling-events-in-an-mvvm-wpf-application/).

Properties should not not really be kicking off asynchronous background operations in their setters. Please refer to my answer here for more information about this:

[Is wrong to invoke an async method from property setter in WPF view model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50175726/is-wrong-to-invoke-an-async-method-from-property-setter-in-wpf-view-model/50177050#50177050)

Comment: -> do I need to add SelectionChanged to CB into xaml?

Comment: No. Just bind to the source property: `<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ProjectList}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedProject}" />`

Comment: I got inf to "consider insert await"....when I put  "await GetTask(_selectedProject)" then I got that await can be only used within an async method

Comment: That's why you shouldn't kick off asynchronous background operations in their setters. Did you read the links I supplied?

Comment: ok - I have changed, but I'm getting all TaskList, not just for selected "Project"....I think that into wrong position I'm running GetTask

Comment: How is this related to your question? If you're getting "all TaskList" there is something wrong with your implementation of the method.

Comment: hi, I had to write one more method to get ID and pass the id to TaskList method and working great, thank you for help @mm8 and others!

Answer (score 0):

You need an event that's fired when the selected item of the ProjectList Combo box changes.

If you were using the code behind, you can just set the SelectionChanged property to point to a function. However it appears that you're using MVVM, so you need to add an interaction trigger to the combobox, a command for the trigger to call and a method for the command to call.

Add this namespace to the window:

```
xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
```

Change your combobox to include the trigger and to expose the SelectedItem

```
           <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ProjectList}" 
                     IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
                     SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedProject}" >
                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ReloadTasksCommand}" />
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
            </ComboBox>
```

Then, in your ViewModel, add the ReloadTasksCommand command. You need to define the command, and the method that it calls.

```
private ICommand reloadTasks;
public ICommand ReloadTasksCommand => this.reloadTasks?? (this.reloadTasks= new RelayCommand(this.ReloadTasks));

public string SelectedProject{ get; set; }

private void ReloadTasks()
{
    GetTasks(this.SelectedProject);
}
```

I've also added a property for the SelectedProject, bound to the SelectedItem of the Project combobox.

RelayCommand is in the GalaSoft.MvvmLight.CommandWpf library. There are others, that's just what I use.

Answer (score 0):

Change combobox like this:

```
       <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ProjectList}" 
                 IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
                 SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedProject}" >                
       </ComboBox>
```

ViewModel:

```
private string _selectedObject;
public string SelectedObject
{
    get { return _selectedObject; }
    set
    {
        _selectedObject = value;
        //OnPropertyChanged(); -- INotifyPropertyChanged no need if Fody
        ReloadTasks();
    }
}

private void ReloadTasks()
{
    GetTasks(SelectedProject);
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by "no need if Fody" ?