# How to create a new Task of type Task?

Tags: c#, .net, task

I have:

```
async Task doWork() { Console.WriteLine("do some async work in this method"); }

Task task = new Task(doWork);   //line X
task.Start();
task.Wait();
```

Line X gives a compilation error:

> CS0407 'Task Form1.doWork()' has the wrong return type

How do I instantiate a new Task `doWork`?

I am able to use the following but it gives me a different set of problems.

```
Task task = doWork();
task.Wait();
```

I want to avoid this second method.  How do I instantiate a new `Task` of type `async Task` at line X?

Comment: `Task task = doWork();` but the task will be synchronous as you don't use `await` inside the function

Comment: You obviously looked at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321321(v=vs.110).aspx to see what type needed - so somewhat unclear what you have problem with... Can you explain what you actually want to achieve with this code?

Comment: @Gusman, yes there are `await` stuff inside `doWork`, but shouldn't it still apply for an empty task?  I stripped off actual code so as not to cloud the issue.

Comment: Sorry, I think I don't understand your question, what do you mean? A task may or may not be executed asynchronously, it depends on what the planner decides, but in the case of an `async` function there is an special consideration, only `awaited` calls will make the function to be executed asynchronously (and not always, depends on the planner), if you don't add any `await` it will be executed synchronously for sure. If what you want is to execute synchronous code in a new asynchronous task then don't mark the function as `async`, return `void` and use `Task.Run(yourFunction);`

Comment: I haven't come to the execution part yet.  I have a compilation problem up to this point.

Comment: I have added more to my question to show what I was trying to do.  However, my question is still on how to overcome the compilation error in `Task task = new Task(doWork)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since doWork() has a return type of `Task`, the declaration needs to be an instance of the generic `Task<TResult>` - i.e. `Task<Task>`

Comment: Yes!  `Task<Task> task = new Task<Task>(doWork)`

Answer (score 3):

In this case, what you probably want is to define `doWork` to have the return type of `void`. Then you can initialize `task` as you've shown using the `Task` constructor with an argument of `Action` ([see docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task(v=vs.110).aspx#Constructors)).

Alternatively, you can use

```
Task task = doWork();
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12144077/async-await-when-to-return-a-task-vs-void) for a discussion of the tradeoffs between the two techniques.

Comment: Thanks.  If I need to have a type of `Task` for `doWork` how should I instantiate it in a `new Task` constructor statement?

Comment: @OldGeezer why do you need to use a `Task` constructor?

Comment: For academic understanding. I was trying to figure out how to call an async task from a non-async task, and to return to the caller only after the called tasks has fully completed.