# To make Task.Delay() from Thread.Sleep()

Tags: c#, multithreading

Can I assume that `doTask` and `doTask2` makes the same job and might be replaced  in code?

```
    public async static void doTask()
    {
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
    }


    public async static void doTask2()
    {
        await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
        });
    }
```

According my experiments both functions acts the same.

Comment: The first one allows the thread servicing the task to return to the operating system. The second blocks the thread.  The first is better.

Comment: Actually really [different](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs,34b191a243434f6a)

Comment: As an aside, [`async void` considered harmful](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12144077/4137916). Avoid it even in examples.

Answer (score 0):

One very very important difference between those is that `Thread.Sleep()` is blocking thread for a duration, means thread won't be available to thread pool, while `Task.Delay()` creates a task and immediately release thread, so that other tasks can use that thread.

`Thread.Sleep` may easily lead to *thread starvation*.

To demonstrate (notice I have changed return type to `Task`):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Task.WaitAll(Enumerable.Range(0, 1000).Select(o => doTask()).ToArray());
    Console.WriteLine("1");
    Task.WaitAll(Enumerable.Range(0, 1000).Select(o => doTask2()).ToArray());
    Console.WriteLine("2");
}

public async static Task doTask() => await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
public async static Task doTask2() => await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)));
```

You will see `1` pretty quickly, but it takes **a lot** of time (several minutes on my 8 core CPU) for `2` to appears.

Rule of thumbs: using threads - use `Thread.Sleep`, using tasks - stick to `Task.Delay`.

Comment: Add to this thread switching and CPU cache invalidation - if the method did useful job, `Sleep()` would force a thread switch *and* empty the CPU's cache from the thread's data