# Catching async operation exception is not working

Tags: c#, exception, uwp, network-programming, async-await

#### I have TCP Client from

`System.Net.Sockets`

```
public async void startTCP()
{
    await client.ConnectAsync(IPAddress, port);
    stream = client.GetStream();
}
```

I surround it with `try catch` block but when I run the code and this exception is raised and VS shows that I'm at

```
UnhandledException += (sender, e) =>
{
    if (global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached) 
        global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
};
```

in `App.g.i.cs`
not where I want to be => Handle the exception myself

> System.Net.Internals.SocketExceptionFactory+ExtendedSocketException:
>   The requested address is not valid in its context
>   255.255.255.255:25565
>          at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndConnect(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>          at System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient.EndConnect(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>          at System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient.<>c.b__21_1(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)
>          at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult
>   iar, Func2 endFunction, Action1 endAction, Task1 promise, Boolean
>   requiresSynchronization)
>       --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>          at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)
>          at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)
>          at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
>          at PersonDesk.Socket.d__10.MoveNext()
>       --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>          at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.<>c.b__6_0(Object
>   state)
>          at System.Threading.WinRTSynchronizationContext.Invoker.InvokeCore()}

The IP address is just placeholder for the exception to be raised

Comment: where is the try...catch??

Comment: Is the `try-catch` inside of the `startTCP` method, or is it where you call it?  `async void` means `startTCP` is fire and forget so you're not going to be able to handle exceptions outside of the method.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [async/await - when to return a Task vs void?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12144077/async-await-when-to-return-a-task-vs-void)

Comment: use "public async Task StartTcpAsync()" instead of "public async void startTCP()"

Comment: The try catch is outside StartTCP, it's where I call it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public async void startTCP()
```

is an `async void`. You shouldn't do that. Because

> I surround it with try catch block

and that is the one thing that doesn't work for `async void`.

---

For a complete answer you will have to show how startTCP() is called. The complete call chain is involved.

It seems to be about WPF so start with the event handler (that *can* be an async void).

Comment: So if I change its type to Task, then I can catch exceptions raised by the async operation in calling method?

Comment: Also it's not wpf but Uwp.

Comment: Thanks for help, I didn't know that. It's working now.