# QUARTZ.NET not executing process

Tags: c#, .net, quartz-scheduler, quartz.net, job-scheduling

I'm using  newest `3.0.6` version of Quartz.net
I want o schedule a process to run each day (currently in example it's every 40seconds but I will change that)
I have method where I call it to execute, however it does not seem to start any process which it should as I initiated it in `Job' class. I'm not sure why it's not trigerring?

```
 public static void Run()
    {

        var isRunning = false;
        IServiceCollection services = new ServiceCollection();
        Startup startup = new Startup();
        var serviceProvider = startup.ConfigureServices(services);
        IWindsorContainer _container = serviceProvider.GetService<IWindsorContainer>();
        while (true)
        {
            if (!isRunning)
            {
                isRunning = true;
                var configuration = _container.Resolve<IConfigurationRoot>();
                var _process = _container.Resolve<Process.Process>();
                int secondsForSleep = Convert.ToUInt16(configuration[Enums.SleepTime]);
                {
                    try
                    {
                        execute();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        isRunning = false;
                        Thread.Sleep(secondsForSleep);
                        _container.Release(_process);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static async void execute()
    {

        // construct a scheduler factory
        NameValueCollection props = new NameValueCollection
        {
            { "quartz.serializer.type", "binary" }
        };
        StdSchedulerFactory factory = new StdSchedulerFactory(props);

        // get a scheduler
        IScheduler sched = await factory.GetScheduler();
        await sched.Start();


        IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<Job>()
            .WithIdentity("myJob", "group1")
            .Build();

        ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
            .WithIdentity("myTrigger", "group1")
            .StartNow()
            .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x
                .WithIntervalInSeconds(1)
                .RepeatForever())
            .Build();

        await sched.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);

    }
}

public class Job : IJob
{
    public async Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        JobKey key = context.JobDetail.Key;
        IServiceCollection services = new ServiceCollection();
        Startup startup = new Startup();
        var serviceProvider = startup.ConfigureServices(services);
        IWindsorContainer _container = serviceProvider.GetService<IWindsorContainer>();
        var configuration = _container.Resolve<IConfigurationRoot>();
        var _process = _container.Resolve<Process.Process>();
        Task t = new Task(() =>
        {
             _process.MainProcess();
        });
       t.Start();
        await t;
    }
}
```

Do I incorrectly set `IJobDetail` object or something?  does anyone had a similar problem? Seems like i did eveerything according to documentation but I still can't get it working

Answer (score 1):

This is not directly the answer to your question but may help you if the problem is related to below.

Look, you have defined the `execute` method as `async void`. As a result, you cannot call it via `await execute()` and so

- your `try-catch` block will not handle any exceptions raised in the `execute` method
- `finally` block runs directly after calling `execute()` method (not waiting for method finishing)

In other words, change your code to `async Task execute()` and `await execute()` and test it again.

---

For more theory I suggest you read this SO: [async/await - when to return a Task vs void?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12144077) and [msdn: Async/Await - Best Practices](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)