# ASP.NET MVC API library

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Using a class library to get data from a web API and referencing it in a MVC project within the same solution.

Keep getting an error while loading the index page in the browser saying I need to mark a Page with `<%@ Page Async="true" %>` or return a TASK. But the controller method will not allow me to use `public async Task MakeCall(string url)` saying type or namespace Task cannot be found.

Library class:

```
public class GetObject
{
    public async Task GetRequest(string url)
    {
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url))
        using (HttpContent content = response.Content)
        {
            string data = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            HttpContentHeaders headers = content.Headers;
        }
    }
}
```

In the controller I use:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        MakeCall("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London&APPID=[APIKEY]");
        return View();
    }

    public async void MakeCall(string url)
    {
        GetObject newCall = new GetObject();
        await newCall.GetRequest(url);
    }
}
```

Comment: Never ever return void from an async method https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12144077/async-await-when-to-return-a-task-vs-void return Task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Avoid `async void` fire and forget methods. Make the code async all the way through making sure to include the necessary namespaces like `using System.Threading.Tasks;`

For example

```
//...other using
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class HomeController : Controller {
    public async Task<ActionResult> Index() {
        await MakeCall("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London&APPID=[APIKEY]");
        return View();
    }

    public async Task MakeCall(string url) {
        GetObject newCall = new GetObject();
        await newCall.GetRequest(url);

    }
}
```