# debug async await method C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging

I have async method like this:

```
public static async void SendInfo(List<MyType> list)
{
   var tasks = list.Select(i => SendAsync(i));
   await Task.WhenAll(tasks); // breakpoint1
}

public static async Task SendAsync(MyType item)
{
   Input input = GetInput(item); //preparation data
   Client client = new Client();
   Output output = await client.CreateInput(input); //breakpoint2
   if (output.Status == Status.Success) //breakpoint3
   {  //Other code }
}
```

`Input`, `Output`, `Client` - proxy-classes from remote API service. Is it possible to debug method `SendAsync` after condition `if`? In my case `breakpoint3` can not be reached. Debug instance ends when I click "Step into" on line with `await client.CreateInput(input)`

Comment: What happens if you remove all breakpoints except for `breakpoint3`, and just run the program?

Comment: No, because `SendInfo` is an `async void` method, control is returned from `SendAsync` back to `SendInfo` on the first `await`

Comment: Your first method should be `async Task` rather than `async void`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12144077/async-await-when-to-return-a-task-vs-void