# How to call async method from Getter and Setter?

Tags: c#, .net, methods, xamarin.forms

I am trying to call async method from property. my code is

```
  private Command _forgotCommand;
  public Command ForgotCommand
  {
    get
     {
       return _forgotCommand ?? (_forgotCommand = new Command(ForgotCommandAssetCommand));
     }
  }

  private async void ForgotCommandAssetCommand()
  {
    await ForgotPasswordApiCall();
  }
```

Now i want to use Task instead of void ( private async void ForgotCommandAssetCommand()) in this line .it gives me error as "Task has wrong return type"
Any Suggestions?

Comment: You probably need to make the `ForgotCommandAssetCommand` return a `Task` instead of `void`, but bear in mind that doing the transition between async code and synchronous code is fraught with peril and headache.

Comment: And your question seems slightly wrong, as you're not really going to call the async method from the getter, instead you're trying to construct a `Command` object around your method, which doesn't work.

Comment: Are you sure you want to do this? See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12144077/async-await-when-to-return-a-task-vs-void) SO question about async and await.