# Use repository with DbContext in ASP.NET Core Authorize-Attribute: "Cannot access a disposed object"

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, attributes, entity-framework-core, dbcontext

For third party authentication, I need a custom `Authorize` attribute. Here a repository (`SessionManager`) class is required to check if the user is logged in.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = true, Inherited = true)]
public class VBAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter {
    public async void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context) {
        var sessionManager = (VBSessionManager)context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService(typeof(VBSessionManager));
        var user = await sessionManager.GetCurrentSessionAsync();
        if (user == null) {
            context.Result = new UnauthorizedResult();
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

In the like `sessionManager.GetCurrentSessionAsync()` the following exception occur:

> Cannot access a disposed object. A common cause of this error is
>   disposing a context that was resolved from dependency injection and
>   then later trying to use the same context instance elsewhere in your
>   application. This may occur if you are calling Dispose() on the
>   context, or wrapping the context in a using statement. If you are
>   using dependency injection, you should let the dependency injection
>   container take care of disposing context instances. Object name:
>   'AsyncDisposer'.

I'm aware of this and don't to any disposing on my own. `VBSessionManager` got my `DbContext` injected in its constructor. Inside `GetCurrentSessionAsync` cookies were checked with LinQ database queries. So no calling of `Dispose`, `using` directives or something like that.

#### Injection in `VBSessionManager`

```
public class VBSessionManager {
    readonly VBDbContext db;
    readonly IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor;
    const string sessionHashCookieName = "xxx";
    VBSession currentSession;

    public VBSessionManager(VBDbContext db, IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor) {
        this.db = db;
        this.contextAccessor = contextAccessor;
    }

    public async Task<VBSession> GetCurrentSessionAsync() {
        if (currentSession == null) {
            string sessionCookie = GetCookieWithoutPrefix(sessionHashCookieName);
            currentSession = await GetSessionAsync(sessionCookie);

            if (currentSession == null) {
                var cookieUser = GetUserFromCookiePassword().Result;
                // No session detected
                if (cookieUser == null) {
                    return null;
                }
                currentSession = db.Sessions.FirstOrDefault(s => s.UserId == cookieUser.Id);
            }
        }
        return currentSession;
    }
    // ...
}
```

#### Injection of services

```
        services.AddDbContext<VBDbContext>(options => {
            string connectionString = Configuration.GetValue<string>("VBConnectionString");
            options.UseMySql(connectionString,
                    mySqlOptions => {
                        mySqlOptions.ServerVersion(new Version(10, 2, 19), ServerType.MariaDb);
                    }
            );
            bool isDev = CurrentEnvironment.IsDevelopment();
            options.EnableSensitiveDataLogging(isDev);
        });

        services.AddScoped<VBSessionManager>();
```

Comment: Try switching from `Scoped` to `Singleton` or `Transient`. For `DI` I reference this (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

Comment: I edited the injection of my DbContext in the question.

Comment: @RyanWilson Tried `Transient` same problem. Singleton doesn't seem good practice since `DbContext` classes are designed to short liveness (see eg https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/15818/169176)

Comment: Can you show your code of `GetCurrentSessionAsync()`? The dbcontext may have been disposed from that.

Comment: @wannadream The method is added in my question.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the usage of `async` cause problems. When I change `OnAuthorization` to a sync method like this, I don't get any errors:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = true, Inherited = true)]
    public class VBAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter {
        public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context) {
            var sessionManager = (VBSessionManager)context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService(typeof(VBSessionManager));
            var user = sessionManager.GetCurrentSessionAsync().Result;
            if (user == null) {
                context.Result = new UnauthorizedResult();
                return;
            }
        }
    }
```

Don't know if those attributes (or maybe only the `AuthorizeAttribute`) isn't designed to work async. For me the current workaround is to use syn method. I also think that this shouldn't decrease performance. But if someone know about the backgrounds and even have a idea how we can use the attribute async, I'd be happy about another answear.

Comment: Just for reference here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/await. An `await` expression does not block the thread on which it is executing. Instead, it causes the compiler to sign up the rest of the async method as a continuation on the awaited task. Control then returns to the caller of the async method. When the task completes, it invokes its continuation, and execution of the async method resumes where it left off. Therefore, when the continuation is invoked here, the dbcontext might have been disposed already.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> public async void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context) {
> ```

Of importance here is the use of `async void`, which is, [according to David Fowler](https://github.com/davidfowl/AspNetCoreDiagnosticScenarios/blob/master/AsyncGuidance.md#async-void), **ALWAYS** bad. With the setup you have here, the call to `OnAuthorization` itself cannot be `await`ed, which means that something like the following is happening:

1. Scoped instances of `VBSessionManager` and `VBDbContext` are being created some amount of time before invoking your `OnAuthorization` method.
2. Your `OnAuthorization` executes and makes a call to `VBSessionManager.GetCurrentSessionAsync`, returning before said method has a chance to complete (due to the use of `async`/`await`).
3. As `OnAuthorization` has completed, the `IDisposable`-implementing `VBDbContext` is disposed.
4. The code inside `VBSessionManager.GetCurrentSessionAsync` is still running - it attempts to use the instance of `VBDbContext` that has been disposed of.

The reason `async void` is being used in your situation is simply because that's what is declared in the [`IAuthorizationFilter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.filters.iauthorizationfilter?view=aspnetcore-2.1) interface - you want to use `await` and the only way to do that is to mark your implementation method as `async` (you can't make it `async Task` because that wouldn't implement the interface).

In terms of a solution to this, I'd agree with Gabriel Luci that using [policy-based authorisation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-2.2) would be the way to go.

Comment: Note that there also is an [`IAsyncAuthorizationFilter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.filters.iasyncauthorizationfilter.onauthorizationasync?view=aspnetcore-2.1#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_Filters_IAsyncAuthorizationFilter_OnAuthorizationAsync_Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_Filters_AuthorizationFilterContext_) which should be used here to allow the filter to be properly asynchronous.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class VBAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{
    public async void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {
        // …

        await something;

        // …
    }
}
```

Having a method `async void` is [almost always a bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12144077/async-await-when-to-return-a-task-vs-void). Asynchronous methods should return a `Task` to make callers able to determine the result of the asynchronous process.

Since you are implementing [`IAuthorizationFilter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.filters.iauthorizationfilter?view=aspnetcore-2.1), you are implementing a **synchronous** authorization filter. You use this when you do not need to do something asynchronously. This is for example true if you just need to look at some of the parameters and then have some ruling to determine whether access is allowed or not.

If you require asynchronous processes, you should **not** make the `void` method asynchronous but instead implement [`IAsyncAuthorizationFilter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.filters.iasyncauthorizationfilter?view=aspnetcore-2.1). This is the interface for implementing an **asynchronous** authorization filter. In that case, the method you need to implement looks a bit different:

```
Task OnAuthorizationAsync(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
```

As you can see, this method returns a `Task` so it can properly do asynchronous processes. In your case, where you want to `await` something inside of the method, you can just do it:

```
public class VBAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute, IAsyncAuthorizationFilter
{
    public async Task OnAuthorizationAsync(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {
        // …

        await something;

        // …
    }
}
```

Now, with a proper asynchronous method that returns a `Task`, the calling system will be able to consume the method properly and the continuation of the request handling will wait for your authorization filter to be processed.

Answer (score 0):

The `OnAuthorization` method is not supposed to be used for verifying authorization. It's just a notification that "hey, authorization is happening now".

That said, [some have used it for this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41348219/1202807). But since you declared it as `async void`, nothing is waiting for this method to finish. That's the root of your exception: by the time the database call is made the request is already finished and the context is disposed. You *can* just remove the `async`....

But the proper solution is use [`IAuthorizationHandler`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authorization.iauthorizationhandler), which is designed for, like the name implies, handling authorization. It has a [`HandleAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authorization.iauthorizationhandler.handleasync) method, which is a proper `async` method that is actually awaited (it waits for your decision on authorization before continuing).

Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31465227/1202807) from a Microsoft employee. You setup the handler, then use it with the regular `AuthorizeAttribute` like this:

```
[Authorize(Policy = "MyCustomPolicy")]
```