# Async Sub() Or Async Function() As Task for Fire and Forget?

Tags: vb.net, asynchronous, async-await, task

I want to do something asynchronously and don't care for the result.
What is the best way to do that?

```
Public Async Function HandlerForSomeEvent() As Task
  'This is where I do stuff

  'Then this is stuff I want to do without waiting for it
  DoStuff()

  'Here I continue doing other stuff
End Function
```

```
Async Sub DoStuff()
  'Doing stuff while the handler continues doing it's stuff
End Sub

'VS

Async Function DoStuff() As Task
  'Doing stuff while the handler continues doing it's stuff
End Function
```

Everyone tells me to use `Function As Task`, but as I don't await it I always get the annoying warning in VS.
What is the difference and why should I do it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/12144077/11683, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx

Comment: `Async Sub` exists only for event handlers. If it's actually an event handler then it should be `Async Sub` but an event handler should also have the appropriate parameters. If it's not an event handler, it should not be `Async Sub`.

Comment: @GSerg That's C#

Comment: @Fox That does not matter.

Comment: @GSerg Are you sure?

Comment: @jmcilhinney Wdym? What's so different about EventHandlers? The HandlerForSomeEvent() is added via AddHandler, yes.

Comment: The whole async/await functionality was created with functions in mind. The only reason that `Async Sub` is allowed is because an event handler MUST be a `Sub` and you might want to await an async method in that event handler. It's a necessary evil so don't use it unless you absolutely have to, because that's the way the system was built.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Huh? But my event handler is actually a function.

Comment: Maybe you should actually write code properly then.

Comment: @Fox: Are you sure you want fire-and-forget? As in, your code doesn't care whether that code completes, or whether it has an exception? If so, then use `Async Function As Task` and ignore the returned task. In C#, you can assign the returned task to a variable to avoid the warning; not sure if the same would work in VB.

Comment: @jmcilhinney That‘s not my code. And the dev says it depends on what the event is asking for.

Comment: @StephenCleary Yes. You mean the _ thingy? I saw that, but haven‘t found a vb.net equivalent.

Comment: @Fox: In C#, it can be any variable name; it doesn't have to be `_`.

Comment: In newer versions of C#, the underscore is specifically a discard, i.e. something used in place of a variable whose value you don't want to use. The value of a discard cannot be used. Before discards were a thing, we just declared a variable but never used its value. You can do the same in VB.

Comment: @Fox, if an event is "asking for" a function then it's not properly written code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The big reasons for using a `Function` that returns a `Task`, rather than an `Async Sub` are two-fold.  The first is exception handling.  If you do something like this, you'll get an uncaught exception which will terminate your application:

```
Public Sub Main()
    Try
        DoSomethingAsync()
    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.WriteLine(ex)
    End Try
End Sub

Private Async Sub DoSomethingAsync()
    Throw New Exception()
End Sub
```

The exception won't get caught by the Try/Catch block, since it's thrown on a separate thread.

However, if you do this, it will get caught and handled:

```
Public Async Sub Main()
    Try
        Await DoSomethingAsync()
    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.WriteLine(ex)
    End Try
End Sub

Private Async Function DoSomethingAsync() As Task
    Throw New Exception()
End Sub
```

The second big reason is because, even though you might not need it now, you might need it later.  If it's already a function that returns a task, then you can use it either way you wish.  If you don't, you can't await on it, or schedule things to happen after it, or abort it, or do any of the other things that you can do with tasks.  So, the question really isn't "why do it?", but rather "why not do it?"

For instance, this outputs "Here" followed by "Done":

```
Public Sub Main()
    DoSomethingAsync()
    Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000)
    Console.WriteLine("Done")
End Sub

Public Async Function DoSomethingAsync() As Task
    Console.WriteLine("Here")
End Function
```

As others have mentioned, to avoid the warning, you can assign the task to a variable like this:

```
Public Sub Main()
    Dim t As Task = DoSomethingAsync()
    Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000)
    Console.WriteLine("Done")
End Sub
```

It works the same either way and runs on its own thread, just like an `Async Sub`.  It doesn't matter if the `Task` variable goes out of scope either.  The task will continue running even if nothing is referencing it.  For instance:

```
Public Sub Main()
    DoSomething()
    Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000)
    Console.WriteLine("Really Done")
End Sub

Public Sub DoSomething()
    Dim t As Task = DoSomethingAsync()
    Console.WriteLine("Done Doing Something")
End Sub

Public Async Function DoSomethingAsync() As Task
    Console.WriteLine("Here")
End Function
```

Comment: When I await it, my handler stops. That's the point. I want to do both things simultanously.

Comment: You don't have to await an async function. Just assign the `Task` it returns to a variable and then you can use that variable later, e.g. test `IsFaulted` to see whether an exception was thrown within it.

Comment: @jmcilhinney The problem with that is that I can‘t use long running code in the event handler itself. I musn‘t exceed 3 seconds. The async stuff takes above 10 seconds. And when I assing the tasks to an var, I would still have to await them later, right?

Comment: @Fox No, if you don't await the task, it still runs on its own, just like the `Async Sub`.  Awaiting it is optional.

Comment: @jmcilhinney But when I asign it and the handler ends before the task, the var would be disposed, wouldn‘t it?

Comment: @Fox I updated my answer with a couple more examples.

Comment: @StevenDoggart Thanks, that explains everything I wanted to know. :)