# How to wait for an asynchronous task to complete in C#?

Tags: c#, async-await

I am working on converting a UIelement into stream using RenderTargetBitmap in uwp application. But I dont know how to make the thread wait till the conversion of stream. I have tried using the suggestions but I could not the find the suitable solution. Any help is much appreciated.

```
   {
      for (int count = 0; count <= Textpage.Children.Count; count++)
      {
         if (Textpage.Children[count] is Viewbox)
         {
            CustomView customView = (Textpage.Children[count] as Viewbox).Child as CustomView;
            UIElement frameworkElement = customView as UIElement;
            (Textpage.Children[count] as Viewbox).Child = null;
            var element = (PdfDocumentPanel.Children[count] as Border).Child as Canvas;
            Textpage.Children.Remove((Textpage.Children[count] as Viewbox));

            SaveCustomAnnotation(frameworkElement, pageIndex, documentToBeSaved);

         }
      }

   }

   Stream savedStream = new MemoryStream();
}

internal async void SaveCustomAnnotation(UIElement element, int pageIndex, PdfLoadedDocument loadedDocument)
{

   Type pageChild = null;

   IRandomAccessStream randomStream;

   randomStream = await Task.Run(() => ConvertToImage(element));

}

public async Task<IRandomAccessStream> ConvertToImage(UIElement element)
{

   InMemoryRandomAccessStream randomAccessStream = null;
   IBuffer pixelBuffer = null;
   RenderTargetBitmap bitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap();


   await bitmap.RenderAsync(element);

   pixelBuffer = await bitmap.GetPixelsAsync();

   var logicalDpi = DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView().LogicalDpi;
   using (randomAccessStream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream())
   {
      var encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(BitmapEncoder.PngEncoderId, randomAccessStream);
      encoder.SetPixelData(
      BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8,
      BitmapAlphaMode.Ignore,
      (uint)bitmap.PixelWidth,
      (uint)bitmap.PixelHeight,
      logicalDpi,
      logicalDpi,
      pixelBuffer.ToArray());
      await encoder.FlushAsync();

   }
   return randomAccessStream;
}
```

I want the SaveCustomannotation method to be entirely completed before moving initializing new memory stream

Comment: Relevant: [Async: When to return a task vs. void](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12144077/async-await-when-to-return-a-task-vs-void). Async void is very different not just because it can't be awaited but because any unhandled exception in an async void method will likely cause your program to crash.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14455293/how-and-when-to-use-async-and-await/44204614#44204614, which has extensive information about the C# `async`/`await` feature. You are hardly the first person to ask a question on SO about not being able to wait for `async void` methods.

Comment: @Jonathon: _"we're going to see a lot of different variations of"_ -- puts it in the same category of `NullReferenceException`. I might have been a bit short, but the fact is, people are posting these kinds of questions without doing any real research. Every reasonable reference discussing the C# `async`/`await` feature, including Microsoft's own documentation, numerous articles on Stack Overflow (including the de facto canonical one I provided the link for), and various experts' blog articles, all explain the hazards of `async void`. It's fundamental.

Answer (score 8):

The problem is here is the *misuse* of `async void`, this prevented you from *awaiting* it. A good rule when you are starting out is, if you type the words `async void` stop... take a step back from your computer, and tell your self there is probably a better way... They should primarily be used for event handlers.

Basically `SaveCustomAnnotation` should return a `Task`

```
internal async Task SaveCustomAnnotation(UIElement element, int pageIndex, PdfLoadedDocument loadedDocument)
```

Then you would need to `await` it

```
await SaveCustomAnnotation(frameworkElement, pageIndex, documentToBeSaved);
```

As such, its calling method should be `async Task` as well (all the way up the call chain), only then should should their be an `async void` and only if it's an event handler.

**Last note**

`Async void` methods have different error-handling semantics. When an exception is thrown out of an `async Task` or `async Task<T>` method, that exception is captured and placed on the `Task`. With `async void` methods, there is no Task object (they run unobserved), so any exceptions thrown out of an `async void` method will be raised directly on the SynchronizationContext that was active when it started.

In short always catch and handle exceptions from with in such methods

---

As [Jonathon Chase](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5402620/jonathon-chase) eluded to (and rightly so).

If this is all it does, you should probably just call it from the main method and await it, as it returns a task anyway and marked async

```
internal async void SaveCustomAnnotation(UIElement element, int pageIndex, PdfLoadedDocument loadedDocument)
{
   Type pageChild = null;
   IRandomAccessStream randomStream;
   randomStream = await Task.Run(() => ConvertToImage(element));
}
```

You could remove the entire method and just replace

```
await SaveCustomAnnotation(frameworkElement, pageIndex, documentToBeSaved);
```

with

```
var readstream = await ConvertToImage(frameworkElement);
```

There is more that is *iffy* about this code, however I think they should probably fall under another question