# Is there a reference document for async aware AppCompatActivity overrides?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

I would like to know if there is a reference document that carefully lists all AppCompatActivity overrides that may be declared async.

For instance, I could mark:

> protected override void OnCreate(Android.OS.Bundle savedInstanceState)

async like this:

> protected override async void OnCreate(Android.OS.Bundle savedInstanceState)

As you can see I'm using [async void, not async Task](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12144426/15186). So Because it is probably the top level async method, it is marked async void.

If there is something out there that goes beyond the scope of AppCompatActivity, that would be a must.

Comment: Events and LifeCycle methods are an exception to the above rule as you do not have control over them, these methods are defaults basically if you want I can add a full-fledged if this does not satisfy you

Comment: why not adding an answer?

Answer (score 0):

It's quite common to make event handlers async void but in this case it's possible that OnResume runs before the Activity is fully initialised in async OnCreate . Since we have no control over whether OnCreate is awaited, the only proper solution is to move long running tasks out with initialisation which is probably a good idea anyway.