# KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback not fire

Tags: c#, azure, unit-testing, mstest, azure-keyvault

I want to get secret from a KeyVault, but the KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback not called.

I created unittest that is MSTest, I have this code:

```
 [TestInitialize]
    public void SetupTest()
    {
        CreateKeyvalut();
    }

    public async void CreateKeyvalut()
    {
        try
        {
            IKeyVaultClient keyVaultClient = GetKeyVaultClient(_clientId, _certificateThumbprint);

            var password = await GetSecretValueAsync(_secretIdentifier, keyVaultClient);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string errorMessage = $"[KeyVault] Error occurred when trying to connect Key Vault. Exception: {ex}";
            Trace.TraceWarning(errorMessage);

            throw;
        }
    }
    public static IKeyVaultClient GetKeyVaultClient(string clientId, string certificateThumbprint) {
        return new KeyVaultClient(AuthenticationCallback(clientId, certificateThumbprint));
    }

    public static KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback AuthenticationCallback(string clientId, string certificateThumbprint)
    {
        return async (authority, resource, scope) =>
        {
            X509Certificate2 certificate = GetCertificate(certificateThumbprint);
            var context = new AuthenticationContext(authority);
            var clientCredentials = new ClientAssertionCertificate(clientId, certificate);
            AuthenticationResult result = await context.AcquireTokenAsync(resource, clientCredentials).ConfigureAwait(false);
            return result.AccessToken;
        };
    }

    public static async Task<string> GetSecretValueAsync(string secretIdentifier, IKeyVaultClient keyVaultClient)
    {
        var secretTask = await keyVaultClient.GetSecretAsync(secretIdentifier);
        return secretTask.Value;
    }
```

But it's never enter to the code inside the KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback AuthenticationCallback.

What is the problem?
The exception I am getting is:

> The thread 0x492c has exited with code 0 (0x0).
>   testhost.exe Warning: 0 : [KeyVault] Error occurred when trying to connect Key Vault. Exception: System.Threading.ThreadAbortException: Thread was being aborted.
>      at Microsoft.Rest.RetryDelegatingHandler.d__15.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.KeyVaultCredential.d__13.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.KeyVaultClient.d__65.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.KeyVaultClientExtensions.d__13.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
>      at <GetSecretValueAsync>d__24.MoveNext() in
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
>      at d__18.MoveNext() in C:\MyProject\src\test\testValidation.cs:line 41

Comment: Can you try using `public async Task SetupTest()`, await the call to `CreateKeyvalut()` and also change the definition of the `CreateKeyvalut` function to `public async Task CreateKeyvalut()` ? Too long to explain here but your can refer to this post to understand async task and async void: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12144077/async-await-when-to-return-a-task-vs-void

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used exact same code and it is stepping in the AuthenticationCallBack function. Please check the screenshot.

[image]

Seems like Call back function throwing error because of the credential issue.

```
**at Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.KeyVaultCredential.d__13.MoveNext()**
```

Please check the credential/certificate and try to debug your call back function.

Hope it helps.

Comment: For me it is working for Local Dev environment, on some servers. Even though it is published as self-contained, it fails on other server.