# Is execution of async Task and async void same

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, async-await

Code examples will use Xamarin Android.

I am extending the `IntentService`. It has few lifecycle methods. In particular, `void OnHandleIntent(Intent intent)` where you do actual work, and `void OnDestroy()` which is called by the system when it sees that the service finished working and it's time to destroy it. For `IntentService`, the end of its life is when `OnHandleIntent` returns.

Being an event-like method, it's OK to use `async void OnHandleIntent`. Consider following code

```
protected override async void OnHandleIntent(Intent intent)
{
    Debug.Out("OnHandleIntent Start");
    await Task.Run(async () => await Task.Delay(1000));
    Debug.Out("OnHandleIntent End");
}

protected override void OnDestroy(Intent intent)
{
    base.OnDestroy();
    Debug.Out("OnDestroy");
}
```

The output is:

```
Debug.Out("OnHandleIntent Start");
Debug.Out("OnDestroy");
Debug.Out("OnHandleIntent End");
```

At the same time, following (blocking) code works as expected

```
protected override void OnHandleIntent(Intent intent)
{
    Debug.Out("OnHandleIntent Start");
    Task.Run(async () => await Task.Delay(1000)).Wait();
    Debug.Out("OnHandleIntent End");
}

protected override void OnDestroy(Intent intent)
{
    base.OnDestroy();
    Debug.Out("OnDestroy");
}
```

The output is:

```
Debug.Out("OnHandleIntent Start");
Debug.Out("OnHandleIntent End");
Debug.Out("OnDestroy");
```

The question is - why does it happens?

Comment: Because the 2nd one is blocking. I don't understand the question, you seem to understand that the 2st one is blocking and the first is not.

Comment: The first one is blocking the execution of the OnHandleIntent method, in the sense that the code after the await will only execute once the task you're awaiting has completed. However, the code that called your OnHandleIntent will continue executing, because once your OnHandleIntent method reaches await, and that task isn't already completed, the method will return. So the calling code moves on and calls Destroy, before your task has completed.

Comment: BTW The use of Task.Run here is only for wasting resources and adding noise to the code. Task.Delay() already returns a task you can await or wait for

Comment: Possible duplicate of [async/await - when to return a Task vs void?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12144077/async-await-when-to-return-a-task-vs-void)

Comment: @FreakyAli No, that question is different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`async void` methods cannot be awaited by the caller (because no Task is returned to wait for).

The first implementation will return before `Delay` is done; it will be executed as a fire and forget operation.

---

Btw.

```
await Task.Run(async () => await Task.Delay(1000))
```

can be

```
await Task.Delay(1000))
```