# C# Windows Async Pinging Network - different results each run

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, ping

I've written a class that asynchronously pings a subnet. It works, however, the number of hosts returned will sometimes change between runs. Some questions:

- Am I doing something wrong in the code below?
- What can I do to make it work better?

The `ScanIPAddressesAsync()` method is called like this:

```
NetworkDiscovery nd = new NetworkDiscovery("192.168.50.");
nd.RaiseIPScanCompleteEvent += HandleScanComplete;
nd.ScanIPAddressesAsync();
```

```
namespace BPSTestTool
{

    public class IPScanCompleteEvent : EventArgs
    {
        public List<String> IPList { get; set; }

        public IPScanCompleteEvent(List<String> _list)
        {
            IPList = _list;
        }
    }

    public class NetworkDiscovery
    {
        private static object m_lockObj = new object();
        private List<String> m_ipsFound = new List<string>();
        private String m_ipBase = null;


        public List<String> IPList
        {
            get { return m_ipsFound; }
        }

        public EventHandler<IPScanCompleteEvent> RaiseIPScanCompleteEvent;

        public NetworkDiscovery(string ipBase)
        {
            this.m_ipBase = ipBase;
        }

        public async void ScanIPAddressesAsync()
        {
            var tasks = new List<Task>();

            m_ipsFound.Clear();
            await Task.Run(() => AsyncScan());
            return;
        }

        private async void AsyncScan()
        {
            List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
            for (int i = 2; i < 255; i++)
            {
                String ip = m_ipBase + i.ToString();

                if (m_ipsFound.Contains(ip) == false)
                {
                    for (int x = 0; x < 2; x++)
                    {
                        Ping p = new Ping();
                        var task = HandlePingReplyAsync(p, ip);
                        tasks.Add(task);
                    }
                }
            }
            await Task.WhenAll(tasks).ContinueWith(t =>
            {
                OnRaiseIPScanCompleteEvent(new IPScanCompleteEvent(m_ipsFound));
            });
        }

        protected virtual void OnRaiseIPScanCompleteEvent(IPScanCompleteEvent args)
        {
            RaiseIPScanCompleteEvent?.Invoke(this, args);
        }

        private async Task HandlePingReplyAsync(Ping ping, String ip)
        {
            PingReply reply = await ping.SendPingAsync(ip, 1500);

            if ( reply != null && reply.Status == System.Net.NetworkInformation.IPStatus.Success)
            {
                lock (m_lockObj)
                {
                    if (m_ipsFound.Contains(ip) == false)
                    {
                        m_ipsFound.Add(ip);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As a side note, instead of `AsyncScan` it is preferable use the `Async` as suffix and name this method `ScanAsync`, to comply with the [guidlines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/task-based-asynchronous-pattern-tap#naming-parameters-and-return-types).

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Thank you for the tip and link. I appreciate it.

Comment: How about an upvote on my question? :-) Seems like it might be useful for others who made the same mistakes I did.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One problem I see is `async void`. The only reason `async void` is even allowed is only for event handlers. If it's not an event handler, it's a red flag.

Asynchronous methods always start running synchronously until the first `await` that acts on an incomplete `Task`. In your code, that is at `await Task.WhenAll(tasks)`. At that point, `AsyncScan` *returns* - before all the tasks have completed. Usually, it would return a `Task` that will let you know when it's done, but since the method signature is `void`, it cannot.

So now look at this:

```
await Task.Run(() => AsyncScan());
```

When `AsyncScan()` returns, then the `Task` returned from `Task.Run` completes and your code moves on, *before all of the pings have finished*.

So when you report your results, the number of results will be random, depending on how many happened to finish before you displayed the results.

If you want make sure that all of the pings are done before continuing, then change `AsyncScan()` to return a `Task`:

```
private async Task AsyncScan()
```

And change the `Task.Run` to await it:

```
await Task.Run(async () => await AsyncScan());
```

However, you could also just get rid of the `Task.Run` and just have this:

```
await AsyncScan();
```

`Task.Run` runs the code in a separate thread. The only reason to do that is in a UI app where you want to move CPU-heavy computations off of the UI thread. When you're just doing network requests like this, that's not necessary.

On top of that, you're also using `async void` here:

```
public async void ScanIPAddressesAsync()
```

Which means that wherever you call `ScanIPAddressesAsync()` is unable to wait until everything is done. Change that to `async Task` and await it too.

Comment: Thank you. I'm now awaiting Task.Run. Is it possible that some devices just aren't consistently replying in time? I will see 16 hosts reply 10 times in a row and then rarely I get back 15 hosts.

Comment: Awaiting `Task.Run` isn't helping you because the `Task` it returns is completing before all the pings have completed. The reason for that is your use of `async void`. You need to change `AsyncScan` to return a `Task` and `await AsyncScan()`.

Comment: I also just noticed `async void ScanIPAddressesAsync()` too. You need to change that as well. I updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks again. Yes, I changed the `AsyncScan` to return a `Task`.

Comment: I appreciate your help very much. I've made the suggested changes. Just for a comparison, I'm running Angry IP Scanner and it too will sometimes return 15 hosts. So I'm thinking my code is more correct now, thank to your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

This code needs a lot of refactoring and bugs like this in concurrency are hard to pinpoint. My bet is on `await Task.Run(() => AsyncScan());` which is wrong because `AsyncScan()` is `async` and `Task.Run(...)` will return before it is complete.

My second guess is `m_ipsFound` which is called a **shared state**. This means there might be many threads simultaneously reading and writing on this. `List<T>` is not a data type for this.

Also as a side point having a `return` in the last line of a method is not adding to the readability and `async void` is a prohibited practice. Always use `async Task` even if you return nothing. You can read more on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23016998/1729973) very good answer.

Comment: Thank you. I have the access to `m_ipsFound` protected with a lock.... I think that prevents thread access issues to that resource... yes?