# C# HttpClient null on second run

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I have a problem. I created the following ViewModel:

```
public class TemplateListViewModel
{
    public double WidthHeight { get; set; }

    public ICommand LoadTemplates => new Command(MyHandler);
    public int CurrentTemplateCountReceived;
    public bool HitBottomOfList = false;
    public ObservableCollection<TemplateSource> sourceList { get; set; }


    public TemplateListViewModel()
    {
        CurrentTemplateCountReceived = 0;
        sourceList = new ObservableCollection<TemplateSource>();

        var mainDisplayInfo = DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo;
        var width = mainDisplayInfo.Width;
        var density = mainDisplayInfo.Density;
        var ScaledWidth = width / density;

        WidthHeight = (ScaledWidth / 2);

        loadingTemplates += onLoadingTemplates;
        LoadTemplateList();
    }

    private event EventHandler loadingTemplates = delegate { };

    private Task LoadTemplateList()
    {
        loadingTemplates(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        return null;
    }

    private async void onLoadingTemplates(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        if (HitBottomOfList == false)
        {
            List<Template> templateList = await App.RestService.GetTemplates(App.User, CurrentTemplateCountReceived);

            if (templateList != null)
            {
                foreach (var template in templateList)
                {
                    ImageSource source = ImageSource.FromUri(new Uri("http://alexander.vreeswijk.eu/memento/" + App.TemplateSource + template.FileName));
                    TemplateSource templateSource = new TemplateSource { Id = template.Id, Source = source, WidthHeight = WidthHeight, FileName = template.FileName };
                    sourceList.Add(templateSource);
                }

                CurrentTemplateCountReceived = sourceList.Count;
            }
            else
            {
                HitBottomOfList = true;
            }
        }
    }

    bool handling = false;

    public async void MyHandler()
    {
        // already handling an event, ignore the new one
        if (handling) return;

        handling = true;

        await LoadTemplateList();

        handling = false;
    }
}
```

And here is the RestService.cs:

```
HttpClient client;
public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }

public RestService()
{
    client = new HttpClient();
    client.MaxResponseContentBufferSize = 256000;
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded"));
}

public async Task<List<Template>> GetTemplates(User user, int offset)
{
    var postData = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
    postData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("un", user.Username));
    postData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("pw", user.Password));
    postData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("offset", offset.ToString()));
    var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(postData);
    var weburl = "mysite.org/myapp/get_templates.php";
    List<Template> response = await PostResponseTemplates(weburl, content);

    return response;
}

public async Task<List<Template>> PostResponseTemplates(string weburl, FormUrlEncodedContent content)
{
    var response = await client.PostAsync(weburl, content);
    var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    if (json != "Nothing")
    {
        var jObject = JObject.Parse(json);
        var templatePropery = jObject["Templates"] as JArray;
        List<Template> templateList = new List<Template>();

        foreach (var property in templatePropery)
        {
            List<Template> propertyList = new List<Template>();
            propertyList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Template>>(property.ToString());
            templateList.AddRange(propertyList);
        }

        var sourcePropery = (JObject)jObject["Source"];
        foreach (var property in sourcePropery)
        {
            string tempplateSource = property.Value.Value<string>();
            App.TemplateSource = tempplateSource;
        }

        return templateList;
    }
    else
    {
        ErrorMessage = json;
        return default(List<Template>);
    }
}
```

The `ICommand` `LoadTemplates => new Command(MyHandler);` gets called when the CollectionView almost hit the bottom of the list, so it would get more data.
Then I created the `MyHandler` to check if there is already an event busy with the webcall to get more data, because it fires the event multiple times.
Finally it executes the `onLoadingTemplates` which gets the data from my webpage.

Now on first run with the `LoadTemplateList();` in the constructor everything works great, but when it executes it like: `await LoadTemplateList();`, when the event is triggered it crashes on the following line in the RestService.cs: `var response = await client.PostAsync(weburl, content);` with the error:

> 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Can someone tell my why this is happening when it gets data when the event is triggered?

Comment: I recommend this read as well: https://josefottosson.se/you-are-probably-still-using-httpclient-wrong-and-it-is-destabilizing-your-software/

Comment: And this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12144077/async-await-when-to-return-a-task-vs-void

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing some detective work here.

Since you said that you are getting a `NullReferenceException`

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

in the line

```
var response = await client.PostAsync(weburl, content);
```

where neither `weburl` or `content` can be null since were created previously in the `GetTemplates` method, it only remains the possibility that `client` is `null` in the former line: if that is the case, you should make sure you are setting the following properties in your client after it is created:

```
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.ConnectionClose = false;
HttpWebRequest.KeepAlive = true;
```

There is a nice [post on HttpClient BestPractices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/shacorn/best-practices-for-using-httpclient-on-services) in the MSFT docs.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I would risk to bet on the current `CollectionView` bug.

It's not the "called second time" case but the renderer just crashes when you change the already loaded bound `ObservableCollection` (and the window with `CollectionView` is hidden).

My first thought was that somewhere in the renderer it was executing on the the calling non-UI thread. 
But even when you try to modify the bound `ObservableCollection` from UI-thread the renderer still crashes.

You can be so kind to report this bug i had no time to do it, actually just using other customized listviews.