# Azure functions not 'awaiting' for task to finish

Tags: c#, async-await, azure-functions

Being honest I'm new to Azure Functions and really basic at C#, I've been looking for answers at some posts here but I'm they didn't work for me or I didn't understand them.

I have a self-triggered function that is doing a API call to Power BI. I want to 'await' until this call finish, but once I start running the function, it just finish without logging some result.

```
public async static void Run(TimerInfo myTimer, TraceWriter log){
    log.Info($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");    
    var credentials = new TokenCredentials(AZ_ACCESS_KEY, AZ_APP_ID);
    var PBIClient = new PowerBIClient(credentials);
    var report = await getReport(PBIClient);
    log.Info($"Response {report}");
  }

public static async Task<Microsoft.PowerBI.Api.V2.Models.Report> getReport(PowerBIClient PBIClient){
    var myTask = Task.Run(() => 
        PBIClient.Reports.GetReport(REPORT_ID)
    );
    var x = await myTask;
    return x;
}
```

Now I have no idea why the function is finishing successfully without logging anything, even if somehow the response returns nothing the function might log `Response` isn't it?

These are the logging results:

```
2020-02-07T20:20:53.354 [Info] Function started (Id=20ccb5b0-abf2-4957-aeb6-b9f26747c1f0)
2020-02-07T20:20:53.604 [Info] C# Timer trigger function executed at: 2/7/2020 8:20:53 PM
2020-02-07T20:20:53.684 [Info] Function completed (Success, Id=20ccb5b0-abf2-4957-aeb6-b9f26747c1f0, Duration=317ms)
```

See? It seems that the function is not respecting the await, but I don't know what I'm doing wrong.
Thanks,

Comment: Should your `Run` method be returning a Task?

Comment: Your function should be `async Task`, the framework will then await your task until it finishes.

Comment: read this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12144077/async-await-when-to-return-a-task-vs-void

Comment: Why are you using Task.Run? That is not gaining you anything.

Comment: [Avoid Async Void](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming#avoid-async-void)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have said [Avoid Async Void](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming#avoid-async-void).  Try changing the first line from

```
public async static void Run(TimerInfo myTimer, TraceWriter log)
```

to

```
public async Task Run(TimerInfo myTimer, TraceWriter log)
```

I'm also seeing TraceWritter in there, what version of Azure functions are you using? The more modern ones use ILogger.  Might want to upgrade?

Comment: Thanks a lot! That worked, do you mean the runtime version? I'm using `Runtime version: 1.0.12967.0 (~1)` and I it seems I can't change it...