# DelegateCommand async await vs Task.Run UI locking

Tags: c#, wpf, async-await, command, task

I want my UI to display a loading overlay once i click on my button.

Option 1

```
MyCommand = new DelegateCommand(() => Task.Run(MyLongRunningTask);

private async Task MyLongRunningTask() {
    IsLoading = true;
    Thread.Sleep(5000);
    IsLoading = false;
}
```

Option 2

```
MyCommand = new DelegateCommand(MyLongRunningMethod);

private async void MyLongRunningMethod() {
    IsLoading = true;
    Thread.Sleep(5000);
    IsLoading = false;
}
```

Option 1 works, option 2 does not. I'm fine with that being the case, although i don't understand why.
But i would really like to avoid having to wrap every execute into () => Task.Run(...).

Since async void seems to be a bad idea, i would like to keep using tasks. But i want to shorten the syntax, so im trying like mad but i cannot figure out how to put the () => Task.Run(..) in a method or class that derives from DelegateCommand.

Why doesnt this compile?

```
    private DelegateCommand GetAsyncCommand(Task t)
    {
        return new DelegateCommand(() => Task.Run(t));
    }
```

Anything similiar to this leads to either compile time errors or i me having to call

```
MyCommand = GetAsyncCommand(MyLongRunningTask());
```

Because of the () braces it instantly executes my task on instantiation.

This seems really convoluted to me. If i have to wrap all my long running tasks into this construct, why cant i build a smarter command that just does that for me given a task?

Edit: I just notices that Option 1 might not lock the UI, but it swallows exceptions which is horrible.

How do i set up a command that does not block the UI and throws any exceptions normally?

Comment: Let me quote from Stephen Cleary's excelant article (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming): 'Async void methods can wreak havoc if the caller isn’t expecting them to be async.'

Comment: He also wrote an AsyncCommand. This will give you a clean syntax. https://github.com/StephenCleary/Mvvm.Async/blob/master/src/Nito.Mvvm.Async/AsyncCommand.cs

Comment: [Avoid async void](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming#avoid-async-void). It is intended for event handlers only.

Comment: The method `MyLongRunningTask` should give you a warning, that you shouldn't ignore: *This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously. Consider using the 'await' operator to await non-blocking API calls, or 'await Task.Run(...)' to do CPU-bound work on a background thread.*

Comment: _"Why doesnt this compile?"_ because `Task.Run()` wants a `Func` or `Action` but you are giving it a `Task`. The compiler should tell you somethind similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Thread.Sleep()` is locking the current thread regardless where it is: in sync or async method. Async method has another way to pause the execution - `await Task.Delay()`.

`async` is not responsible on `Threading`, `async` implements a [state mashine](https://medium.com/@deep_blue_day/long-story-short-async-await-best-practices-in-net-1f39d7d84050) that executes your code asynchroniously splitting it by awaitable parts. `Task` is responsible on Threading.

replace

```csharp
Thread.Sleep(5000);
```

with

```csharp
await Task.Delay(5000);
```

Note that `async void` is bad practice. [Look](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12144077/async-await-when-to-return-a-task-vs-void).

Comment: But this would not help in releaving the UI thread from doing CPU heavy work. I have the impression that the `Thread.Sleep(...)` is simulation for a computation that does CPU heavy work. If that is the case it would be wise to use `Task.Run()` to run that code on a thread-pool thread.

Comment: @Ackdari agree but are you sure that heavy work in `async Task` is executing definetly in current Thread? I'm not. And I'm not sure that if I run 2 extra heavy async methods it will cause thread lock in 2nd method before completion of the 1st method. Thus `Sleep()` os not exact "heavy task" emulation but pure locking.