# C# HttpClient Async-Await - Unable to Guarantee 'A' Before 'B'

Tags: c#, async-await, console-application, httpclient

I'm trying to write a C# console application that uses HttpClient to scrape web pages.  When FunctionOne is called, what's the best way to ensure that "A" is written to the console before "B"?  Whenever I run my code, "B" is always written before "A".  Thanks in advance for the help!

```
public class MyClass
{
    public void FunctionOne(string url)
    {   
        FunctionTwoAsync(url);

        Console.WriteLine("B");
    }

    private async void FunctionTwoAsync(string url)
    {
        var httpClient = new HttpClient();
        var htmlContent = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(url);
        var htmlDocument = new HtmlDocument();
        htmlDocument.LoadHtml(htmlContent);

        Console.WriteLine("A");
    }
}
```

Comment: Watch out for async void https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12144077/async-await-when-to-return-a-task-vs-void

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `FunctionTwoAsync` method is an `async` method, it means this method works Asynchronous.

When you need the result of methode or need this method completes, you must be use `await` keyword for `async` method

So, Change your code like this:

```
public class MyClass {

public async Task FunctionOne(string url)
{   
    await FunctionTwoAsync(url);

    Console.WriteLine("B");
}

private async Task FunctionTwoAsync(string url)
{
    var httpClient = new HttpClient();
    var htmlContent = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(url);
    var htmlDocument = new HtmlDocument();
    htmlDocument.LoadHtml(htmlContent);

    Console.WriteLine("A");
}
}
```

Comment: This explains nothing. It would be a better answer if you explain what the problem is and why this code works

Comment: This worked, thanks @Mofid.Moghimi!  I paired your sample solution with the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12144077/async-await-when-to-return-a-task-vs-void) that @Linus provided above to get clarity on the 'what' and 'why'.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

To make A before B, you neeb to await FunctionTwoAsync and make FunctionOne an async function

```
 public async void FunctionOne(string url)
 {   
    await FunctionTwoAsync(url);

    Console.WriteLine("B");
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should make the FunctionOne also async and wait for the execution of the second function:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public async Task FunctionOne(string url)
    {   
        await FunctionTwoAsync(url);

        Console.WriteLine("B");
    }

    private async Task FunctionTwoAsync(string url)
    {
        var httpClient = new HttpClient();
        var htmlContent = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(url);
        var htmlDocument = new HtmlDocument();
        htmlDocument.LoadHtml(htmlContent);

        Console.WriteLine("A");
    }
}
```

Comment: An `async void` method cannot be awaited, because it does not return an awaitable object e.g. `Task`.