# C# Async recursive function not working properly?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, recursion

This is my code :

```
  class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        update();
    }

    static async void update()
    {
        await Task.Delay(100);
        Console.WriteLine("X");
        update();
    }
}
```

Console never outputs any text at all, and I have no clue why. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [async/await - when to return a Task vs void?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12144077/async-await-when-to-return-a-task-vs-void)

Comment: [Avoid async void](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming#avoid-async-void). Use `async Task` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Main` method is not `async`, so it doesn't wait for your `update` method. Also, your `update` method should return a `Task` so your `Main` method can await it.

```cs
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    await update();
}

static async Task update()
{
    await Task.Delay(100);
    Console.WriteLine("X");
    await update();
}
```

Comment: @Selvin Thanks I'll update the answer

Comment: Would that not cause an stack overflow?