# How do I wait until one method is finished in C#?

Tags: c#

In my application I'm getting data from another source and uploading those data to the tables.

So I wrote it as,(there are some codes before that, but I start with what I want to ask)

```
StartProcess();

FirstMonth();

SecondMonth();

ThirdMonth();


private async void StartProcess()
{
  try
   {
     var progress = new Progress<int>(value => { progressBar1.Value = value; });
     await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(() => SaveData(progress));
     MessageBox.Show("Upload Complete");

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
     throw ex;
    }
}

private void SaveData(IProgress<int> progress)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.RowCount; i++)//data reading one by one from excel
   {
    string PartNo = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
    string PartDescription = "";
    string PartModel = "";
    int AvaQty = int.Parse(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString());
    
    DbLoad obj = new DbLoad();
    if (obj.UploadStock(PartNo, PartDescription, PartModel, AvaQty))
     {

     }
     else
      {
       MessageBox.Show("An unexpected error has occurred.Please contact your system administrator");
       }

     }
    MessageBox.Show("Upload Success");
}
```

This is the FirstMonth Method

```
private void FirstMonth()
{
 try
  {
   OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection("OraConnection");
   con.Open();
   OracleCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
   cmd.CommandText = "Query";
   cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
   OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

   DataTable dt = new DataTable();
   dt.Load(dr);
   dataGridView1.DataSource = dt.DefaultView;
   UploadFirstMonth();
   con.Close();
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
   MessageBox.Show("error" + ex);
  }

}

private void UploadFirstMonth()
{
  for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.RowCount; i++)
  {
   string PartNo = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
   int AvaQty = int.Parse(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString());
   DbLoad obj = new DbLoad();
   if (obj.UpdateFirstMonth(PartNo, AvaQty))
   {}
   else
   {
    MessageBox.Show("An unexpected error has occurred on First Month Upload.Please contact your system administrator");
   }
  }
}
```

Normally this has more than 15000 records to be upload to the database. Once it uploaded to the database I want to trigger the second method **FirstMonth** to start the method.

But the current Issue is before finishing the **StartProcess()** the second method is starting to process. How I stop that ? I want to trigger second method once the first method is completely finished.

Comment: So, you know that compiler warning that says "because this call is not awaited, execution continues.."; you're now here with the complaint "execution is continuing!" - always pay close attention to warnings too; just because your app works even if there are hundreds of them doesn't mean it's error free

Comment: `throw ex;` -> please don't. Just remove the try-catch if you're not going to do anything with the exception. `throw ex;` is almost never something you want

Comment: Indeed; the only time you should realistically have an async void is probably in a windows forms event handler

Comment: any time you type the words `async void`, you're *probably* making a mistake; there *are* some scenarios where it is necessary (UI event-handlers being the classic example), but the rest of the time...?

Comment: Don't access windows forms controls in this way; you're risking accessing them from threads other than the threads that created them

Comment: Show us the contents of  `DbLoad.UploadStock();`

Comment: @CaiusJard I have update the question and pasted the code.

Comment: Erm.. I can see some bits, but UploadStock is missing. UpdateFirstMonth has appeared too, and doesn't have any definition..

Answer (score 0):

If you are tying to wait for the end of the proccess on a sync method on the main thread, then you can simply hit `StartProcess().Result` or `StartProcess.Wait()` to run those synchronous. You can also call yor second method when all the tasks you need are completed, you can check it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall?view=net-6.0)

In the case you are calling the tasks you want to be completed inside an `async` method you can simply use the `async await` pattern and `await StartProcess()`.

I would also suggest you in general to avoid the  `async void` patter.
[Link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12144077/async-await-when-to-return-a-task-vs-void)

Answer (score 0):

you need to change the return type from void to Task in order to wait for the method to complete since the return type is void it will not wait for completion even if you have awaited the call, and then you need to use await keyword for completing the execution. like below.

```
async someFunction (){
    await StartProcess();   
    FirstMonth();
}


private async Task StartProcess()
{
   try
   {
       var progress = new Progress<int>(value => { progressBar1.Value = value; 
       });
       await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(() => SaveData(progress));
       MessageBox.Show("Upload Complete");

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
       throw ex;
    }
 }
```

Comment: There are other serious mistakes in the OP's code that I believe should also be addressed..

Answer (score -1):

You need to `await StartProcess()` before calling `FirstMonth()`

This will force execution to wait for `StartProcess` to finish before it starts `FirstMonth`:

```
await StartProcess();

FirstMonth();
```

Note that the method that executes these needs to be marked async:

```
public async Task Foo()
{
    await StartProcess();
    FirstMonth();
}
```

You should probably `await` both `StartProcess` and `FirstMonth` though.