# Why this call is not awaited

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, async-await

I don't really know why my code is breaking up at line 24, when it's trying to execute the first await method. I mean, it doesn't show me nor a compilation nor execution error. I already installed all 5 Jsonize packages the guide says. I think the problem could be because the call is not awaited, but I don't really know what might be happening.

I'm trying to follow step by step this guide about what I want to achieve. This is my goal:
https://github.com/JackWFinlay/jsonize

Here is my entire code:

```cs
using Jsonize;
using Jsonize.Parser;
using Jsonize.Serializer;
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace JsonizeExample
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
            Testy();
        }

        public static async void Testy()
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                string url = @"https://jackfinlay.com";

                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url);

                string html = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                // The use of the parameterless constructors will use default settings.
                JsonizeParser parser = new JsonizeParser();
                JsonizeSerializer serializer = new JsonizeSerializer();
                Jsonizer jsonizer = new Jsonizer(parser, serializer);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

I'm working on Visual Studio 2019, .NET Core 3.1, C#.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The title already explains the problem. `Testy` is not awaited, so the program will exit before that method even has a chance to execute. Change the signature to `async Task` and await it. Change `Main` to `async Task` as well. `async void` is *only* meant for asynchronous event handlers, nothing else. An async method that doesn't return anything should be `async Task`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [async/await - when to return a Task vs void?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12144077/async-await-when-to-return-a-task-vs-void)

Comment: The sample in the code you linked to is `async Task<string> Testy`. Not `async void`

Comment: Thanks a lot dude. I did as you said and it actually flows correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you compiling your code you get the following warning pointing to `Testy();`:

> warning CS4014: Because this call is not awaited, execution of the
> current method continues before the call is completed.

Without applying `await` to the `Testy();` your program will not await this method to be finishing execution and the program will terminating, when more likely the `Testy()` method is performing the `await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();` call.

Applying `await` to the `Testy();` call will lead you to change the  `public static void Main(string[] args)` signature to `static public async Task Main(string[] args)`.

See the following note from the documentation [Don't block, await instead](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/#dont-block-await-instead) post:

> NOTE: The `Main` method returns `Task`, despite not having a `return`
> expression—**this is by design**. For more information, see [Evaluation of
> a void-returning async function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/classes#14153-evaluation-of-a-void-returning-async-function).

Therefore change you application accordingly:

```cs
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
    await Testy();
}

public static async Task Testy()
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        ... your code           
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try returning Task or Task instead of void.
or
await Testy();

Comment: This should be a comment. Without `await` the method won't be awaited by itself.