# C# Pub-Sub example how to make function called in the subscriber async when notification published by publisher

Tags: c#, event-handling, delegates, publish-subscribe

Hope I phrased the question correctly, feel free to give suggestions in order to make it more clear.

I basically just need to make this function async:

> protected virtual void OnNotificationReceived(Publisher p,
> NotificationEvent e)

Not sure how to modify the rest of the code to make it work, please help.

Publisher class

```
 class Publisher{
    
        //publishers name
        public string PublisherName { get; private set; }
    
        //publishers notification interval
        public int NotificationInterval { get; private set; }
    
        // declare a delegate function
        public delegate void Notify(Publisher p, NotificationEvent e);
    
        // declare an event variable of the delegate function
        public event Notify OnPublish;
    
        // class constructor
        public Publisher(string _publisherName, int _notificationInterval){
            PublisherName = _publisherName;
            NotificationInterval = _notificationInterval;
        }
    
        //publish function publishes a Notification Event
        public void Publish(){
    
            while (true){
    
                // fire event after certain interval
                Thread.Sleep(NotificationInterval);
    
                if (OnPublish != null)
                {
                    NotificationEvent notificationObj = new NotificationEvent(DateTime.Now, "New Notification Arrived from");
                    OnPublish(this, notificationObj);
                }
                Thread.Yield();
            }
        }
    }
```

Subscriber class

```
 class Subscriber{
    
        public string SubscriberName { get; private set; }
    
        public Subscriber(string _subscriberName){
            SubscriberName = _subscriberName;
        }
    
        // This function subscribe to the events of the publisher
        public void Subscribe(Publisher p){
    
            // register OnNotificationReceived with publisher event
            p.OnPublish += OnNotificationReceived;  // multicast delegate 
    
        }
    
        // This function unsubscribe from the events of the publisher
        public void Unsubscribe(Publisher p){
    
            // unregister OnNotificationReceived from publisher
            p.OnPublish -= OnNotificationReceived;  // multicast delegate 
        }
    
        // It get executed when the event published by the Publisher
        // ***I want to make this method async here:***
        protected virtual void OnNotificationReceived(Publisher p, NotificationEvent e){
    
            Console.WriteLine("Hey " + SubscriberName + ", " + e.NotificationMessage +" - "+ p.PublisherName + " at " + e.NotificationDate);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the `async` keyword. You can do this even though the method returns `void` instead of `Task`.

```cs
protected virtual /**/ async /**/ void OnNotificationReceived(Publisher p, NotificationEvent e){
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)); // See? It's async
    Console.WriteLine("Hey " + SubscriberName + ", " + e.NotificationMessage +" - "+ p.PublisherName + " at " + e.NotificationDate);
}
```

[See it compile](https://dotnetfiddle.net/TcF929)

Just be aware that in my code above, the call to `Console.WriteLine` will happen *asynchronously* (approximately one second later) instead of *synchronously* as before. This can lead to race conditions if you're not prepared for it.

Also be aware that whoever calls this async void method will have no way of knowing when it completes. If callers need to know when it completes then make the method return a `Task`; then callers can `await` it.

Also be aware that any exceptions thrown in an `async void` method will most likely be lost. That's not *necessarily* the case ([example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.appdomain.unhandledexception?view=net-6.0), [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.unhandledexception?view=windowsdesktop-6.0)... assuming you subscribe to those events). So it might be wise to wrap all the code in your `async void` method in a try/catch and respond intelligently to any thrown exceptions.

Here are other thoughts on returning `Task` vs `void`:
[async/await - when to return a Task vs void?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12144077/async-await-when-to-return-a-task-vs-void)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I get an error here:  p.OnPublish += OnNotificationReceived saying: 
"Task Subscriber.OnNotificationReceived(Publisher p, NotificationEvent e) has wrong return type"
when i change it to async Task

Comment: @RazvanEmil In this case you will want to return `void` instead of `Task`. Events are usually fire-and-forget, meaning the caller of `OnNotificationReceived` (i.e. whoever raises the event) does not need to know when it completes. I only mentioned returning a `Task` because it'll be something to think about in the future in other scenarios.

Comment: yes good point I dont think I need to await it, within the OnNotificationReceived function in my code i am just further firing an MQTT message to an MQTT broker, the function is async, using a library,but I dont think I need to await that.... so I just added FireMQTTMessage(message).ConfigureAwait(false) not sure if there is a problem with that...

Comment: `async void` is almost always a terribad idea; I don't see anything that would make it OK here

Comment: @MarcGravell True. I added another caveat about losing exceptions and linked to another question discussing the differences. It probably would have been more productive for me to link to that from the beginning ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯