# Calling a static async method from a Page results in InteropServices.COMException error

Tags: c#, json, winui-3

I'm calling an async method which is located in App.xaml.cs file. I'm calling this method from my c# file of home page (HomePageView.xaml.cs). I don't know why but I'm getting this error:

`System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread. (0x8001010E (RPC_E_WRONG_THREAD))'`
This exception is thrown on the line starting with `TEXT1_STRING`.

The `UpdateText()` method is:

```cs
private async void UpdateText()
{
    HomePageViewText1.Text = "error text";

    TEXT1_STRING = Task.Run(() => App.GetJSONAsync()).Result;
    
    return;
}
```

`GetJSONAsync()` method code can be found below:

```cs
internal static async Task<string> GetJSONAsync()
{
    string JSON = null;

    using HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    try
    {
        JSON = await client.GetStringAsync("https://www.example.com/api/getdata");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        log.Error("Error fetching JSON" + e.ToString());
    }

    return JSON;
}
```

Can anyone help me why this is happening? I'm not very familiar with Threading, Marshals etc. with C#. Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried `TEXT1_STRING = await App.GetJSONAsync();` ? The async function should return a `Task`.

Comment: Interesting, I first tried this and it did not work, (async/await deadlock) but converting this removed the exception. I'll delete this question

Comment: I think it'd worth leaving the question up in case someone else has a similar error message and googles it

Comment: This makes no sense.  There's no COM components in the code shown.

Comment: Is there something I should look for or maybe add here? I'm calling the `UpdateText()` function in `HomePageView()`.

Comment: Have you solved your problem?

Comment: I did solve the problem using my answer below. @M.M suggested that I should change the method header to be Task instead of void however that caused deadlock so just changing the line that starts with `TEXT1_STRING` was enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this exception by applying @M.M's solution. What I did was to return
`TEXT1_STRING = Task.Run(() => App.GetJSONAsync()).Result;` to `TEXT1_STRING = await App.GetJSONAync();`

After this change, the exception was not thrown and program was able to build and run successfully.

Fixed version of `UpdateText()`:

```cs
private async void UpdateText()
{
    HomePageViewText1.Text = "error text";

    TEXT1_STRING = await App.GetJSONAync();
    
    return;
}
```

Comment: did you also change to returning `Task` rather than `void` ?

Answer (score 0):

The first function should be:

```
private async Task UpdateText()
{
    HomePageViewText1.Text = "error text";

    TEXT1_STRING = await GetJSONAsync();

    return;
}
```

As an `async` function it should contain an `await` statement . Trying to make an async function run synchronously, by using `Task(....).Result()` or otherwise, is a bit of a minefield, see [this blog](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) for some explanation.

See also [async/await - when to return a Task vs void?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12144426/1505939) -- exception handling is different for `async void` functions than `async Task` functions.

Comment: if I use this, I get: `The 'await' operator can only be used within an async method. Consider marking this method with the 'async' modifier and changing its return type to 'Task'. `

Comment: if I apply your solution I get deadlock

Comment: @cptalpdeniz you said a moment ago that this fixed the problem; and the error message you post suggests the method was not actually marked `async` as you have shown in the question?

Comment: The code only works if I leave UpdateText() function header as `private async void UpdateText()`. If I change it to `Task` then deadlock occurs.

Comment: @cptalpdeniz OK, well glad to hear it is working although I think the deadlock on returning `Task` might be suggestive of further issues that you will have to address sooner or later

Comment: I see, since I don't understand these topics a lot, I'm working on learning more and hopefully I'll see where the error is in the future is and maybe revisit this. @M.M