# Async void versus Task discard syntax in event handler

Tags: c#, async-await, event-handling

Where an event handler calls async code:

```
MyObject.MyEvent += MyHandler;
```

Is there any advantage of using one of these patterns over the other?:

```
// option 1: async void + await
private async void MyHandler(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
  await DoSomethingAsync();
  DoSomethingElse();
}

// option 2: void + discard syntax
private void MyHandler(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
  _ = DoSomethingAsync();
  DoSomethingElse();
}
```

Comment: Regarding the option 2, is really your intention to run the `DoSomethingAsync` and `DoSomethingElse` concurrently?

Answer (score 2):

In case of option 1 `DoSomethingElse()` will execute only after `DoSomethingAsync()` finished executing.

In case of option 2 `DoSomethingElse()` will not wait for `DoSomethingAsync()` to finish.

Answer (score 1):

```cs
private async void MyHandler(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
  await DoSomethingAsync();
  DoSomethingElse();
}
```

The execution path of this function *completely* executes `DoSomethingAsync()`,
*then* runs `DoSomethingElse()`. The exact thread that both of these operations run on is undefined (meaning it can run anywhere). Additionally, any errors in `DoSomethingAsync` will prevent `DoSomethingElse()` from running, and will call an event handler on your `SynchronizationContext` sometime down the line alerting you of the failure.

```
private void MyHandler(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
  _ = DoSomethingAsync();
  DoSomethingElse();
}
```

The execution path of this function runs `DoSomethingAsync()` until the first `await` expression, where it *schedules* the execution of the rest of `DoSomethingAsync()`. It will then run `DoSomethingElse()` synchronously.

This means that everything after the first `await` of `DoSomethingAsync` can run anywhere, at any time, and is not necessarily going to run before `DoSomethingElse()`. *You will never know if any `await`s in `DoSomethingAsync` run at all, or whether it runs successfully*, as any errors in `DoSomethingAsync()` will not prevent `DoSomethingElse()` from running (including those in the synchronous block!). In practice, if this is all you need from this pattern, then you should just use try/catch.

To clarify, The first synchronous block of `DoSomethingAsync()` will run until the first await. After that, you are in the blind. Note that `DoSomethingAsync` failing in your `void` pattern will behave exactly the same as `MyHandler` failing in your `async void` pattern.

---

Your first pattern (`async void`) strongly defines the control-flow (do A, then do B), while your second (`void`) pattern loosely defines the control flow (do A until the first `await`, do B, and sometime in the future finish doing A.).

Note that both patterns are exactly the same to whatever code is calling your event handler; each just has different benefits and consequences for *your* end of the stick.

You can read more about return types and exception behavior with these patterns here:

- [async/await - when to return a Task vs void?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12144077/async-await-when-to-return-a-task-vs-void)
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/asynchronous-programming/async-return-types

Comment: _"The execution path of this function schedules the execution of DoSomethingAsync(), then runs DoSomethingElse()" "You will never know if DoSomethingAsync runs at all,[...]"_ - I feel like this part of your answer requires clarification. The code won't just "schedule the execution"of DoSomethingAsync, it will actually enter the function immediately, and will run synchronously until it encounters the first `await` inside it, at which point it will exit (return to `MyHandler`) and enter `DoSomethingElse`.

Comment: @Orion You are correct, and this is defined behavior in the C# specification, but I just wasn't sure of a way to clearly word it without confusing people. I'll try and work something in.

Comment: "The exact thread that both of these operations run on is undefined" is a bit misleading. This seems to be an event handler in a GUI application, so there is a synchronization context which will make `DoSomethingElse` continue on the UI thread.

Comment: Ah, that’s a semantics error on my part. Undefined here meaning not defined in any standard I could find, not that the thread itself is completely unpredictable 100% of the time or actually invokes undefined behavior.