# How to tell C# that I am consciously not going to wait the task execution?

Tags: c#

In below example, the method `displaySnackbarForAWhile` of `SnackbarService` class is asynchronous because it using the timer-like `await Task.Delay` functionality:

```cs
using FrontEndFramework.Components.Abstractions;

namespace FrontEndFramework.Components.Snackbar;


public abstract class SnackbarService
{

  public static event Action? onStateChanged;
  protected static void NotifyStateChanged() => SnackbarService.onStateChanged?.Invoke();

  protected const ushort MESSAGE_DISPLAYING_DURATION__SECONDS = 5;

  public static async System.Threading.Tasks.Task displaySnackbarForAWhile(
    string message,
    object decorativeVariation,
    ushort displayingDuration__seconds = SnackbarService.MESSAGE_DISPLAYING_DURATION__SECONDS
  )
  {

    SnackbarService.message = message;
    
    string validDecoration = ""; 
    
    YDF_ComponentsHelper.AssignDecorativeVariationIfItIsValid<Snackbar.StandardDecorativeVariations>(
      decorativeVariation, Snackbar.CustomDecorativeVariations, ref validDecoration
    );

    SnackbarService.decoration = validDecoration;
    SnackbarService.isSnackbarDisplaying = true;

    await Task.Delay(
      (int)TimeSpan.FromSeconds(displayingDuration__seconds).TotalMilliseconds
    );

    SnackbarService.hideSnackbar();
    
  }

}
```

The below method `onNewTaskEditingCompleted` which using the `SnackbarService.displaySnackbarForAWhile` works as intended including catch-block.
Once execution will enter to `catch`, the snackbar will be displayed, the exception will be printed without delay and them the blocking loading overlay will be hidden:

```cs
public partial class TasksManagementPageContent : ComponentBase
{
  
  private async void onNewTaskEditingCompleted(CommonSolution.Gateways.ITaskGateway.Adding.RequestData requestData)
  {
    
    BlockingLoadingOverlayService.displayBlockingLoadingOverlay();

    try
    {
      await TasksSharedState.addTask(requestData);
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {

      SnackbarService.displaySnackbarForAWhile(
        message: "The error occurred during the saving of new task data.",
        decorativeVariation: Snackbar.StandardDecorativeVariations.error
      );

      Debug.WriteLine(exception);
      return;

    }
    finally
    {
      BlockingLoadingOverlayService.dismissBlockingLoadingOverlay();  
    }


    await SnackbarService.displaySnackbarForAWhile(
      message: "The new task has been saved",
      decorativeVariation: Snackbar.StandardDecorativeVariations.success
    );
    
  }
}
```

But, there is the **CS4014** warning:

> Because this call is not awaited, execution of the current method continues before the call is completed. Consider applying the 'await' operator to the result of the call.

If I'll await the `SnackbarService.displaySnackbarForAWhile()`, the `Debug.WriteLine(exception);` (and then `BlockingLoadingOverlayService.dismissBlockingLoadingOverlay()`)will be called only after the snackbar will be hidden.

How to solve the **CS4014** correctly?

Comment: You may want to read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12144077/async-await-when-to-return-a-task-vs-void (not exactly duplicate, but highlights some problems you need to think about).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not going to await async function. You can assign it to a variable:

```cs
var task = SnackbarService.displaySnackbarForAWhile(/*arguments*/);
_ = SnackbarService.displaySnackbarForAWhile(/*arguments*/); // Or use discard
```

## Example

```cs
using System.Diagnostics;

var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
System.Console.WriteLine($"Before: {watch.ElapsedMilliseconds}ms");
_ = run();
System.Console.WriteLine($"After {watch.ElapsedMilliseconds}ms");

await Task.Delay(4000);
System.Console.WriteLine($"Program Exit {watch.ElapsedMilliseconds}ms");

async Task<bool> run()
{
    System.Console.WriteLine($"Start {watch.ElapsedMilliseconds}ms");
    await Task.Delay(3000);
    System.Console.WriteLine($"Complete {watch.ElapsedMilliseconds}ms");
    return true;
}
// Output:
// Before: 0ms
// Start 5ms
// After 8ms
// Complete 3025ms
// Program Exit 4018ms
```